# O que é big-endian e qual a diferença para little-endian?

Tags: c, c++, portabilidade

Tenho uma noção básica do que vem a ser o big-endian e o little-endian, porem não consigo ver exatamente como a forma diferente de armazenamento pode complicar a portabilidade.

Qual problema de portabilidade ocorre devido a big-endian vs little-endian e quais as formas comuns de se resolver o mesmo?

Observar que estou anotando a pergunta tanto em C como em C++ devido a ser um problema que eu acredito atingir ambas as linguagens. Deste modo uma resposta que aborde qualquer uma das linguagens será aceita.

Comment: https://arqufs2008.wordpress.com/2008/05/26/little-endian-vs-big-endian/

Comment: Ok, mas o que isto implica na portabilidade?

Comment: Supoe que eu tinha de te enviar um numero de telefone. Mas tem que ser através de folhas de papel, em que cada folha só leva 1 digito. Se não souberes a ordem em que eu escrevi os meus papeis, quando os receberes nao consegues refazer o numero.

Comment: `20150212` data "big endian" (com o "big end" no principio); `12022015` data "little endian" (com o "little end" no principio)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sua noção é correta. Você já sabe que a forma como os registradores tratam de dados numéricos variam. Vou me basear [nesse documento da IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-endianc/) para responder.

## O problema

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE* fp;

    /* Our example data structure */
    struct {
        char one[4];
        int  two;
        char three[4];
    } data;

    /* Fill our structure with data */
    strcpy(data.one, "foo");
    data.two = 0x01234567;
    strcpy(data.three, "bar");

    /* Write it to a file */
    fp = fopen("output", "wb");
    if (fp) {
        fwrite(&data, sizeof (data), 1, fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/Endianess.c).

Este código tem problemas de *endianess*. Dependendo da plataforma ele apresenta um resultado diferente porque cada plataforma organiza os *bytes* de um tipo numérico com o *byte* mais significativo primeiro ou por último. Em algumas plataformas a estrutura seria montada assim:

```
foo..4Vxbar.
```

Em outras, assim:

```
foo.xV4.bar.
```

Note que os caracteres não são afetados, apenas os números. Por isto se você gravar um arquivo com dados em formato numérico ele poderá ser lido erroneamente em outra plataforma. Se é sabido que um arquivo poderá circular entre plataformas, ele terá que garantir que o formato dos números no arquivo seja identificado e convertido adequadamente antes de sua utilização.

[image: Big Endian]

[image: Little Endian]

## Como resolver o problema

Nem sempre é possível identificar a significância dos *bytes*. O arquivo deve informar (nele próprio ou por documentação) qual a significância usada e os programas que acessá-lo deve entender esta informação. Em comunicação por rede deve haver um protocolo que passe esta informação ou documente isto. Nem sempre tem-se controle sobre estas possibilidades.

Até para facilitar é comum solucionar o problema gravando/transmitindo o dado numérico em um formato de texto. Quando usa-se um texto você tem certeza que cada *byte* estará na ordem que você espera. Quando falo em texto, pode haver duas soluções:

- transformar um número em uma representação textual do número, ou seja, um inteiro que valha `12359` passa ser representado por uma *string*  `"12359"`. Isto não é muito eficiente em termos de tamanho e processamento mas resolve o problema
- tratar os *bytes* como caracteres e saber como montar o número

  Isto não quer dizer que você pode simplesmente fazer um *cast* do texto em número pura e simplesmente. Um *cast* é justamente o que causa o problema porque ele considera que a significância dos *bytes* estão na ordem esperada. O que não é verdade se o dado veio de uma plataforma com significância diferente.

#### Como a plataforma trabalha

É fácil saber qual é a significância da plataforma:

```
const int i = 1;
#define is_bigendian() ( (*(char*)&i) == 0 )

int main(void) {
    int val;
    char *ptr;
    ptr = (char*) &val;
    val = 0x12345678;
    if (is_bigendian()) {
        printf(“%X.%X.%X.%X\n", u.c[0], u.c[1], u.c[2], u.c[3]);
    } else {
        printf(“%X.%X.%X.%X\n", u.c[3], u.c[2], u.c[1], u.c[0]);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/Endianess1.c).

#### Como saber a significância do dado a ser manipulado

Se por documentação ou por informação disponibilizada em um dado recebido você sabe a significância do que será trabalhado e sabe a significância da plataforma, sabe se precisará fazer alguma transformação, possivelmente inverter os *bytes* antes de usar se a opção é usar a segunda forma listada acima.

Se você não sabe e não tem como verificar qual é a significância da informação, não tem como resolver o problema. Há um problema arquitetural da aplicação aí.

Em último caso claro que é possível pedir a ajuda do usuário. Em alguns casos pode ser que o usuário consiga identificar alguns valores se estão corretos ou não. Então deve-se apresentar os dados obtidos com as duas formas e perguntar qual faz mais sentido. Isto pode apresentar falhas mas é uma solução extrema se nada mais for possível. O grau de confiabilidade será dado pela capacidade do usuário de identificar corretamente. Não estou dizendo que isto é recomendado, mas é a única solução.

Claro que dados que garantidamente vieram da própria plataforma não são preocupação.

Então fica a lição que dados que tem potencial para serem passados para outras plataformas - e isto é muito comum hoje em dia - precisam ter uma informação de significância em algum lugar junto ao dado transmitido ou deve ser bem documentado.

## Exemplo de reordenamento

O exemplo do documento mostra o uso do TCP que é documentado que trabalha com *big endian*. Portando as plataformas com esta significância podem ser ligeiramente mais eficientes por não precisam fazer o reordenamento dos *bytes*.

Uma forma para reordenar os *bytes*:

```
const int i = 1;
#define is_bigendian() ( (*(char*)&i) == 0 )

short reverseShort(short s) {
    unsigned char c1, c2;
    if (is_bigendian()) {
        return s;
    } else {
        c1 = s & 255;
        c2 = (s >> 8) & 255;
        return (c1 << 8) + c2;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("%d", reverseShort((short)1234));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/Endianess2.c).

## O problema não acontece com qualquer número.

Evidentemente números com apenas um *byte* não têm este problema. Isto costuma afetar `short`, `int`, `long`, `float` e `double`, com ou sem sinal (o sinal obviamente produz resultado ainda mais errados, se é que isto é possível :) )

## Conclusão

Para facilitar todo mundo usa soluções prontas, formatos e protocolos que tratam isto e deixam transparente para a aplicação. Você só deve se preocupar com isto se estiver fazendo algo de baixo nível.

[Artigo na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: Um artigo interessante que li a um tempo atrás e que mostra como as vezes complicamos sem necessidade o tratamento de ordenação de bytes é este [aqui](http://commandcenter.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html) (Em inglês). É interessante como ele apresenta uma solução que independe da ordem da sua máquina e é mais simples que a normalmente utilizada, como a que você apresentou.

Comment: @OP, a essência da resposta (código) está correto, porém o macro "is_bigendian" é perigoso mesmo tendo Assembly válido (não me pergunte por que).

Comment: Use uma union de char[2] e short = 0x1234 e cheque se char[0] = 0x12. Esse código funcionou comigo quando estudava sobre o assunto em C++.

Comment: @LucasHenrique Por que? :) Coloquei mais para ilustrar a forma de acordo com o artigo que estava usando. Eu nunca precisei lidar com isto mas se precisava certamente eu iria pesquisar as melhores formas para se chegar em um resultado aceitável.

Comment: @bigown certo. Eu pesquisei-as para que use-a da melhor maneira :P.