# Separar os bytes que formam um número inteiro?

Tags: lua

Supondo que eu tenho esse número positivo:

```
local uint = 2000;
```

como posso obter os bytes que compõe-o separadamente? Por exemplo:

```
print(sepbytes(uint));
-- 7, 208
```

**Minha tentativa:**

```
local function sepbytes(cur)
  local t = {};
  repeat
    cur = cur / 16;
    table.insert(t, 1, cur);
  until cur <= 0
  return table.unpack(t);
end

print(sepbytes(2e3));
```

**Resultado:**

```
0   9.8813129168249e-324    1.5316035021079e-322    2.4703282292062e-321    3.95252516673e-320  6.324040266768e-319 1.0118464426829e-317    1.6189543082926e-316    2.5903268932682e-315    4.144523029229e-314 6.6312368467665e-313    1.0609978954826e-311    1.6975966327722e-310    2.7161546124355e-309    4.3458473798969e-308    6.953355807835e-307 1.1125369292536e-305    1.7800590868058e-304    2.8480945388892e-303    4.5569512622227e-302    7.2911220195564e-301    1.166579523129e-299 1.8665272370064e-298    2.9864435792103e-297    4.7783097267365e-296    7.6452955627784e-295    1.2232472900445e-293    1.9571956640713e-292    3.131513062514e-291 5.0104209000224e-290    8.0166734400359e-289    1.2826677504057e-287    2.0522684006492e-286    3.2836294410387e-285    5.2538071056619e-284    8.4060913690591e-283    1.3449746190495e-281    2.1519593904791e-280    3.4431350247666e-279    5.5090160396266e-278    8.8144256634025e-277    1.4103081061444e-275    2.256492969831e-274 3.6103887517297e-273    5.7766220027675e-272    9.2425952044279e-271    1.4788152327085e-269    2.3661043723335e-268    3.7857669957337e-267    6.0572271931739e-266    9.6915635090782e-265    1.5506501614525e-263    2.481040258324e-262 3.9696644133184e-261    6.3514630613095e-260    1.0162340898095e-258    1.6259745436952e-257    2.6015592699124e-256    4.1624948318598e-255    6.6599917309757e-254    1.0655986769561e-252    1.7049578831298e-251    2.7279326130076e-250    4.3646921808122e-249    6.9835074892995e-248    1.1173611982879e-246    1.7877779172607e-245    2.8604446676171e-244    4.5767114681874e-243    7.3227383490998e-242    1.171638135856e-240 1.8746210173695e-239    2.9993936277913e-238    4.799029804466e-237 7.6784476871456e-236    1.2285516299433e-234    1.9656826079093e-233    3.1450921726549e-232    5.0321474762478e-231    8.0514359619964e-230    1.2882297539194e-228    2.0611676062711e-227    3.2978681700337e-226    5.276589072054e-225 8.4425425152864e-224    1.3508068024458e-222    2.1612908839133e-221    3.4580654142613e-220    5.5329046628181e-219    8.8526474605089e-218    1.4164235936814e-216    2.2662777498903e-215    3.6260443998244e-214    5.8016710397191e-213    9.2826736635506e-212    1.4852277861681e-210    2.3763644578689e-209    3.8021831325903e-208    6.0834930121445e-207    9.7335888194312e-206    1.557374211109e-204 2.4917987377744e-203    3.986877980439e-202 6.3790047687024e-201    1.0206407629924e-199    1.6330252207878e-198    2.6128403532605e-197    4.1805445652168e-196    6.6888713043469e-195    1.0702194086955e-193    1.7123510539128e-192    2.7397616862605e-191    4.3836186980168e-190    7.0137899168269e-189    1.1222063866923e-187    1.7955302187077e-186    2.8728483499323e-185    4.5965573598917e-184    7.3544917758267e-183    1.1767186841323e-181    1.8827498946116e-180    3.0123998313786e-179    4.8198397302058e-178    7.7117435683292e-177    1.2338789709327e-175    1.9742063534923e-174    3.1587301655877e-173    5.0539682649402e-172    8.0863492239044e-171    1.2938158758247e-169    2.0701054013195e-168    3.3121686421112e-167    5.299469827378e-166 8.4791517238048e-165    1.3566642758088e-163    2.170662841294e-162 3.4730605460704e-161    5.5568968737127e-160    8.8910349979403e-159    1.4225655996704e-157    2.2761049594727e-156    3.6417679351564e-155    5.8268286962502e-154    9.3229259140003e-153    1.49166814624e-151  2.3866690339841e-150    3.8186704543745e-149    6.1098727269992e-148    9.7757963631987e-147    1.5641274181118e-145    2.5026038689789e-144    4.0041661903662e-143    6.4066659045859e-142    1.0250665447337e-140    1.640106471574e-139 2.6241703545184e-138    4.1986725672294e-137    6.7178761075671e-136    1.0748601772107e-134    1.7197762835372e-133    2.7516420536595e-132    4.4026272858552e-131    7.0442036573683e-130    1.1270725851789e-128    1.8033161362863e-127    2.885305818058e-126 4.6164893088929e-125    7.3863828942286e-124    1.1818212630766e-122    1.8909140209225e-121    3.025462433476e-120 4.8407398935616e-119    7.7451838296986e-118    1.2392294127518e-116
1.9827670604029e-115    3.1724272966446e-114    5.0758836746313e-113    8.1214138794101e-112    1.2994262207056e-110    2.079081953129e-109 3.3265311250064e-108    5.3224498000102e-107    8.5159196800163e-106    1.3625471488026e-104    2.1800754380842e-103    3.4881207009347e-102    5.5809931214955e-101    8.9295889943928e-100    1.4287342391028e-98 2.2859747825645e-97 3.6575596521033e-96 5.8520954433652e-95 9.3633527093844e-94 1.4981364335015e-92 2.3970182936024e-91 3.8352292697638e-90 6.1363668316222e-89 9.8181869305955e-88 1.5709099088953e-86 2.5134558542324e-85 4.0215293667719e-84 6.434446986835e-83  1.0295115178936e-81 1.6472184286298e-80 2.6355494858076e-79 4.2168791772922e-78 6.7470066836675e-77 1.0795210693868e-75 1.7272337110189e-74 2.7635739376302e-73 4.4217183002084e-72 7.0747492803334e-71 1.1319598848533e-69 1.8111358157653e-68 2.8978173052245e-67 4.6365076883593e-66 7.4184123013748e-65 1.18694596822e-63   1.899113549152e-62  3.0385816786431e-61 4.861730685829e-60  7.7787690973264e-59 1.2446030555722e-57 1.9913648889156e-56 3.1861838222649e-55 5.0978941156238e-54 8.1566305849982e-53 1.3050608935997e-51 2.0880974297595e-50 3.3409558876152e-49 5.3455294201844e-48 8.552847072295e-47  1.3684555315672e-45 2.1895288505075e-44 3.503246160812e-43  5.6051938572993e-42 8.9683101716788e-41 1.4349296274686e-39 2.2958874039498e-38 3.6734198463196e-37 5.8774717541114e-36 9.4039548065783e-35 1.5046327690525e-33 2.407412430484e-32  3.8518598887745e-31 6.1629758220392e-30 9.8607613152626e-29 1.577721810442e-27  2.5243548967072e-26 4.0389678347316e-25 6.4623485355705e-24 1.0339757656913e-22 1.6543612251061e-21 2.6469779601697e-20 4.2351647362715e-19 6.7762635780344e-18 1.0842021724855e-16 1.7347234759768e-15 2.7755575615629e-14 4.4408920985006e-13 7.105427357601e-12  1.1368683772162e-10 1.8189894035459e-09 2.9103830456734e-08 4.6566128730774e-07 7.4505805969238e-06 0.00011920928955078 0.0019073486328125  0.030517578125  0.48828125  7.8125  125
```

**Resultado esperado:**

```
7, 208
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar operações de bits para isso, sem mexer muito no que estava fazendo:

```
local function sepbytes(num)
    local t = {};
    local byte = 0;
    repeat
        table.insert(t, 1, bit32.band(bit32.rshift(num, byte), 0xff));
        byte = byte + 8
    until byte > 24
    return table.unpack(t);
end

print(sepbytes(2000));
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/RDD5qC). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/beekqphl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/SplitBytes.lua).

Isso depende de [*endianess*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50457/101). Se a arquitetura for diferente precisa ir de 24 até 0 e não mais de 0 até 24. Se não puder garantir que vai rodar em uma arquitetura específica precisa descobrir qual é e usar um ou outro, aí já é outro problema.

Dá para verificar mais ou menos bytes, esse verifica no 0, 8, 16 e 24, ou seja, 4 bytes (32 bites). Basta mudar até onde vai.

Se precisar descartar os que tem valores 0 não significativos, poderia filtrar isso mais com uma condição. Eu acho que seria equivocado fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

Com ajuda de alguns comentários na minha outra [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41492292#41495514) eu consegui simplificar minha função para retornar 2 bytes fixos:

```
local function InParts(num)
    return (num & (0xff << 8)) >> 8, num & 0xff;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente também

```
string.byte(string.pack("i4",uint),1,4)
```

Ajuste 4 para o tamanho dos seus números.