# Qual a diferença entre os operadores & e &&?

Tags: c#, operadores, curto-circuito

Estava fazendo um código simples com um `if` de duas condições. Tudo funcionou normal e depois que eu fui ler, percebi que tinha escrito `condicao & condicao2` ao invés de usar **`&&`**. Mesmo com este "*typo*" o código está completamente funcional.

Um exemplo simplório onde os dois `WriteLine` são executados. O exemplo pode ser [executado no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LyQkAr)

```
bool condicao1 = true, condicao2 = true;

if(condicao1 && condicao2)
    WriteLine("Primeiro if - OK");

if(condicao1 & condicao2)
    WriteLine("Segundo if - OK");
```

Qual é o nome do operador **`&`**?

Estes operadores sempre serão intercambiáveis? Se sim, há alguma diferença entre usar um e outro? Caso não, qual é a diferença semântica entre os dois?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/224468/1658

Answer (score 21, accepted):

O `&` é o operador de bits *and*, então ele compara cada bit do dado verificado e resulta em 1 sempre que o bit correspondente nos dois operandos são 1, afinal o *and* só é verdadeiro quando ambos são verdadeiros, caso contrário o resultado será 0, e assim manipula-se bits.

Essa é a função primária dele e sabendo usá-lo bem pode-se fazer algumas otimizações (não que precise sempre) evitando que existam *branches* desnecessários que é uma operação de processador bem custosa. Operações com ele podem ser vistas em [Como ligar um bit em um número?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175345/101).

Claro que se você fizer isso em um dado booleano, só 1 bit é relevante, e eles serão calculados e o resulto pode ser usado como um booleano, então serve em um `if`, por exemplo.

É preciso entender que o `if` só aceita um booleano. Então ele só pode aplicar em operandos que valham 00000000 ou 00000001 e seja do tipo booleano. Apenas o último bit é relevante, sem considerar [*endianess*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50457/101).

Em uma expressão booleana mais complexa com mais de uma subexpressão este operador sempre executará todas subexpressões (os operandos do `&`), não importa o resultado, em alguns casos é o que deseja, em outros não precisa se preocupar com a segunda subexpressão quando o resultado da primeiro é 0 (falso), então pode-se usar o `&&`.

O `&&` é o *and* lógico e não trabalha com bits, só com o resultado booleano. Ele tem [curto-circuito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154056/101), então ele só executa a segunda subexpressão se a primeira for verdadeira.

O mesmo vale para o `|` e `||`, só que neste caso é um *or*, então no `||` se o primeiro for verdadeiro não executa o segundo porque basta uma subexpressão ser verdadeira para tudo ser considerado verdadeiro.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var x = 1;
        var y = 2;
        var a = x & y;
        var b = x == 1;
        var c = y == 2;
        var d = x & y;
        var e = (x & y) == 0;
        WriteLine(a);
        WriteLine(d); //note que é um inteiro
        WriteLine(e);
        //if (x & y) WriteLine("ok"); //não funciona porque if espera um bool e o resultado é int
        if (b & c) WriteLine("ok"); else WriteLine(" não ok");
        if (Teste(x) & Teste(y)) WriteLine("&  - ok"); else WriteLine("&");
        if (Teste(x) && Teste(y)) WriteLine("&& - ok"); else WriteLine("&&");
        if (Teste(x) | Teste(y)) WriteLine("|  - ok"); else WriteLine("|");
        if (Teste(x) || Teste(y)) WriteLine("|| - ok"); else WriteLine("||");
        if (Teste(y) & Teste(x)) WriteLine("&  - ok"); else WriteLine("&");
        if (Teste(y) && Teste(x)) WriteLine("&& - ok"); else WriteLine("&&");
        if (Teste(y) | Teste(x)) WriteLine("|  - ok"); else WriteLine("|");
        if (Teste(y) || Teste(x)) WriteLine("|| - ok"); else WriteLine("||");
    }
    public static bool Teste(int x) {
        WriteLine($"Executou {x}");
        return x == 2;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Jom0Et). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DimArs). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Operator/And.cs).

Pode ver mais em [Para que servem os operadores | & << >>?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52949/101).

A [tabela verdade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) determina os resultados de álgebra booleana.

[image: Tabela verdade]

Answer (score 14):

> há alguma diferença entre usar um e outro?

Sim.

---

Comparar com dois `&` significa fazer *short circuit*. Ex:

```
if((condicao1) & (condicao2)) { }
```

Ao fazer isso, o runtime vai verificar as duas condições antes de decidir se o resultado é verdadeiro ou falso.
Numa expressão `AND`, se uma das condições for falsa, não importa quantas outras condições forem positivas, o resultado será `false`.

Ao fazer:

```
if((condicao1) && (condicao2)) { }
```

Se a primeira condição for falsa, o runtime nem vai perder tempo calculando/resolvendo a segunda, pois sabe que o resultado do todo será `false`.

---

Tabela da verdade:

```
| A | B | S |
|---|---|---|
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
```

---

[Aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/2a723cdk.aspx) tem um link da documentação do operador `&&` que explica exatamente isso.

Answer (score 2):

Como mencionado, o && é um operador lógico, utilizado geralmente para operação condicionais.

```
if(x > 0 && x < 20){ ... }
```

O & simples possui uma funcionalidade um pouco diferente, já que trabalha sobre **bits**. Em geral o & é muito utilizado na programação de microcontroladores por exemplo, onde você aplica mascaras de bits para desativar uma saída

```
portA = readPortA();
portA = portA & 0b11111110;
writePortA;
```

Esse pseudo codigo estaria desativando a saída 0 da PORTA, já que uma leitura possível seria:

```
//estado lido: 0b01010101
//estado retornado: 0b01010100

portA = readPortA();
// portA = 0b01010101
portA = portA & 0b11111110;
// força o ultimo bit a 0
// 0b01010101 & 0b11111110 = 0b01010100
writePortA;
```

Answer (score -3):

O && você comparar as duas expressões:
1==1&& 2==2=> só será true se as duas condições forem verdadeiras. Ele tem curto-circuito, então ele só executa a segunda parte se a primeira for verdadeira.
O & é a mesma coisa mais diferente do && não possui curto-circuito e tem a comparação de bit a bit.