# Operações lógicas em Python 2.7

Tags: python, característica-linguagem

Ao realizar operações lógicas em Python 2.7, notei algo estranho. Por exemplo, ao fazer `5 and 6`, obtêm-se como resultado `6`. Ora, o correto seria 4, pois, convertendo esses valores para binário, têm-se `101` and `110`, que daria `100`, pois em operações lógicas "and", o resultado só é verdadeiro, ou seja, `1`, quando suas entradas também forem verdadeiras, ou seja, possuírem valor `1`. Por que esse comportamento "estranho"? Há algo faltando nessa operação?

Comment: O operador lógico `and` é diferente de `&`, que é o operador *e* bit a bit. Se você fizer `print(5 & 6)`, a saída será 4, como esperado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você pretende usar é o operador **`&`**, que é o operador *bit* a *bit*. Ele que faz a operação da forma que você descreveu na sua pergunta.

Usando o **`and`** este é exatamente o comportamento esperado. Ele é um **operador lógico**, tem funcionamento parecido com **`&`**, mas não completamente igual.

A própria documentação do Python explica isto:

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> Note that neither `and` nor `or` restrict the value and type they return to False and True, but rather return the last evaluated argument.

Em tradução livre:

> A expressão  `x and y` primeiro avalia `x`; se `x` é falso, seu valor é retornado; caso contrário, `y` é avaliado e o valor resultante é retornado.
>
> Note que nem o `and` nem o `or` restringem os valores ou tipos retornados a `False` e `True`, em vez disto, retornam o último argumento avaliado.

Tentando explicar com mais calma.

Bem, vejamos, **`x and y`** só vai retornar `True` caso as duas expressões sejam verdadeiras, certo? Sendo assim, se `x` for `False` não é necessário avaliar a expressão `y`, porque, de qualquer maneira o resultado vai ser `False`.

Agora, se `x` for `True`, a expressão `y` também precisa ser avaliada e o retorno da expressão vai ser o valor de `y`. O que faz completo sentido porque, se o lado esquerdo da expressão é `True` quem decide o "resultado" dela é sempre o valor mais a direita, se ele for `True` o resultado será, obviamente, `True` e se for `False` o resultado será `False` também.

No seu caso específico acontece o seguinte, a primeira expressão é avaliada, como ela não é `False`, a segunda é avaliada e seu valor é retornado.

---

Talvez seja interessante ler esta pergunta que eu fiz. Pra você se localizar, o `&&` do C# é como o `and` do Python. E o `&` é igual pros dois.

- [Qual a diferença entre os operadores & e &&?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190579/18246)

Comment: Obrigado, LINQ.

Answer (score 5):

O operador `and` trata seus operandos como booleanos. Isto é, quando você faz:

```
5 and 6
```

O interpretador do Python irá fazer o *cast* dos operandos para `bool` e depois verificar o resultado. Algo como `bool(5) and bool(6)`, mas não exatamente isso. O que acontece de fato tem relação com o curto circuito em expressões lógicas. Isto é, o Python verificará o primeiro operando, verificando o resultado de `bool(5)`; se for verdadeiro e a operação for `and`, o resultado final dependerá apenas do segundo operando, sendo este retornado, pois `True and X` será sempre `X`, independente de seu valor. Se você alterar o operador para `or`, isto é, fazer `5 or 6`, a mesma lógica ocorre, porém, como `bool(5)` é tratado como verdadeiro, o curto circuito da expressão acontece e é retornado o valor 5, pois `True or X` é sempre verdadeiro, independente de `X`.

A lógica que você descreveu esperando o resultado 4 é conhecida como lógica bit a bit. Para tal, será necessário utilizar o operador `&` para `bitwise and` ou `|` para `bitwise or`. Ou seja, o resultado 4, que é esperado, pode ser obtido fazendo:

```
print(5 & 6)
```

Ou o valor 7 ao fazer `print(5 | 6)`, pois `101 | 110` resulta em `111`.

---

Para completar a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214308/5878) do LINQ, que por sua vez completa essa, o código equivalente (não oficial) do operador `and` é:

```
def _and_ (x, y):

    # Interpreta o valor de x como booleano:
    eval_x = bool(x)

    # Se for falso:
    if not eval_x:

        # Retorna o valor de x:
        return x

    # Caso contrário, retorna y:
    return y
```

Se fizer `print(5 and 6 == _and_(5, 6))` verá que a saída é `True`.

Já para o operador `or`:

```
def _or_ (x, y):

    # Interpreta o valor de x como booleano:
    eval_x = bool(x)

    # Se for verdadeiro:
    if eval_x:

        # Retorna o valor de x:
        return x

    # Caso contrário, retorna y:
    return y
```

Como comentado da resposta supracitada, o retorno do operador não é, necessariamente, do tipo booleano, pois os valores retornados são `x` ou `y`, e, desta forma, o tipo retornado será o tipo de `x` ou de `y`, dependendo de qual foi retornado pelo operador. Fato que pode ser comprovado fazendo `print(type(5 and 6))`, resultando em `<class 'int'>`, ou `print(type([] and 6))` que resulta em `<class 'list'>`.

Comment: Obrigado, Anderson! Sua resposta também me ajudou.