# Como funciona o operador 'in' no Python

Tags: python

Alguém poderia me explicar qual a lógica do operador 'in' do python? Eu fiz alguns testes no idle e ainda não consigo entender como ele funciona.

```
>>> (2 or 10) in range(1,6)
True
>>> (10 or 2) in range(1,6)
False
```

No caso acima, porque ele encontraria 2 ou 10 no range de 1 a 5, mas não encontra 10 ou 2 no range de 1 a 5.

```
>>> (10 and 2) in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
True
```

Como assim, encontrou 10 e 2 no range de 1 a 9?

Tenho certeza que estou entendendo errado esse operador.

Answer (score 9):

O problema não está no operador `in`, mas sim no operador lógico `or` e `and` que você utilizou. Fazer:

```
>>> (2 or 10) in range(1,6)
```

Não verifica se os números 2 e 10 estão no `range(1, 6)`. O que ocorre é que o Python irá primeiro analisar a expressão lógica `2 or 10` e verificar se o resultado desta expressão pertence ao `range(1, 6)`. O Python interpreta qualquer valor inteiro diferente de zero como verdadeiro e somente o zero como falso. Então fazer `2 or 10`, para o Python, é o mesmo que `True or True`. Neste caso, como o operador lógico é o `or` e o primeiro operando é verdadeiro, não importará o valor do segundo, então é retornado o valor do primeiro, 2. Assim, o Python irá verificar apenas se 2 está em `range(1, 6)`, retornando verdadeiro. Este comportamento de retornar um valor antes de analisar a expressão lógica inteira é chamada de curto-circuito.

[Operações lógicas em Python 2.7](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214296/5878) (Mais sobre como o Python avalia a expressão lógica)

Então, no outro caso, `(10 or 2) in range(1,6)`, a mesma lógica ocorre. O número 10 será analisado como verdadeiro e sendo o operador `or`, ocorre novamente o curto-circuito da expressão lógica, retornando como resultado o ´roprio valor 10. Assim, o Python irá verificar se `10 in range(1, 6)`, retornando falso.

Na terceira expressão:

```
>>> (10 and 2) in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

A única coisa que muda é o operador lógico, de `or` para `and`. Sendo `and`, não ocorrerá o curto-circuito da expressão lógica quando o primeiro operando for verdadeiro, então o segundo operando, 2, será analisado e retornado. Assim, o retorno de `10 and 2` será 2 e o Python irá verificar se ele está em `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`, retornando verdadeiro.

Basta fazer o teste:

```
# (2 or 10) ocorre o curto-circuito, retornando o primeiro operando: 2
print(2 or 10)

# (10 or 2) ocorre o curto-circuito, retornando o primeiro operando: 10
print(10 or 2)

# (2 and 10) não ocorre o curto-circuito, retornando o segundo operando: 10
print(2 and 10)

# (10 and 2) não ocorre o curto-circuito, retornando o segundo operando: 2
print(10 and 2)
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/tExJKD).

---

O curto-circuito ocorre quando:

- No operador `or`, o primeiro operando é verdadeiro, pois `True or X` sempre será verdadeiro independente de `X`;
- No operador `and`, o primeiro operando é falso, pois `False and X` sempre será falso independente de `X`;

Se no operador `or` o primeiro operando for falso, é retornado o valor do segundo operando. Se no operador `and` o primeiro operando for verdadeiro, é retornado o valor do segundo operando.

---

Para verificar se uma lista de números está contida em outra lista com Python, você precisará fazer:

```
>>> all(x in range(1, 6) for x in [2, 10])
```

Neste caso, todos os elementos de `[2, 10]` serão percorridos através de `x` e verificados, um a um, se pertencem ao conjunto `range(1, 6)`. Se pelo menos um não pertencer, a função `all` retornará falso. Retornará verdadeiro se todos os elementos pertencerem ao outro conjunto.

Ou seja, o código abaixo resulta em `False`, pois 10 não pertence a `range(1, 6)`:

```
>>> all(x in range(1, 6) for x in [2, 10])
```

Mas o código abaixo retorna `True`, pois todos os elementos pertencem a `range(1, 6)`:

```
>>> all(x in range(1, 6) for x in [2, 4])
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/doj8kA).

Outra forma é trabalhar com conjuntos matemáticos. Para saber se o conjunto `B` é um sub-conjunto do conjunto `A`, em Python, basta fazer:

```
>>> B.issubset(A)
```

Desta forma, para saber se `[2, 10]` é um sub-conjunto de `range(1, 6)`, fazemos:

```
>>> A = set(range(1, 6))
>>> B = set([2, 10])
>>> B.issubset(A)
False
```

Retorna falso, pois 10 não pertence ao conjunto `A`. Porém, se testar com o conjunto `[2, 3]`:

```
>>> A = set(range(1, 6))
>>> B = set([2, 3])
>>> B.issubset(A)
True
```

Pois o conjunto `{2, 3}` é um sub-conjunto de `range(1, 6))`.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/wR5PCG).

Comment: Achei muito boa sua explicação, estava eu aqui quebrando a cabeça para saber porque [1,2,3] in [1,2,3] retornava False. Ainda assim, não achei muito amigável para iniciantes. Mas acho que eu me acostumo. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Na verdade é, mas provavelmente você ainda está interpretando de forma equivocada em primeira vista. Isso mudará com o tempo e verá que tal notação faz sentido, pois fazer `[1,2,3] in [1,2,3]` verifica se a primeira lista inteira pertence à segunda. A verificação não é feita elemento a elemento.