# Interseção entre dois conjuntos(elemento que está no conjunto A e no B ao mesmo tempo)

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Estou tentando fazer uma função que retorne a interseção entre dois conjuntos:

```
def intersecao(conjuntoA, conjuntoB):
    inter = [x for x in range(1,12) if x in conjuntoA and conjuntoB]
    return inter

a = [2,4,6,7,10]
b = [3,4,6,8,10,11]
print(intersecao(a,b))
```

Esta função deveria retornar: [4,6,10]
Mas está retornando: [2, 4, 6, 7, 10]
Já tentei sem ser por compreensão de listas, mas o resultado é o mesmo...
Alguém poderia apontar onde está o erro por gentileza?
Pq até transformando em binário eu já tentei, e mesmo assim não da certo :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema no seu código é a condição dentro do construtor da lista:

```
inter = [x for x in range(1,12) if x in conjuntoA and conjuntoB]
```

Você está percorrendo todos os valores de 1 a 11 e verificando se este está no conjunto A. A ideia seria verificar se também está no conjunto B, mas a sintaxe está errada. Fazendo:

```
x in conjuntoA and conjuntoB
```

O que ocorre, de fato, é que o Python irá verificar se `x` pertence ao conjunto A e o retorno desta verificação será feito o `and` com conjunto B. Visto que o conjunto B é uma lista não vazia, o Python irá considerar `conjuntoB` como verdadeiro sempre, então a lista final conterá todos os números de 1 a 11 que satisfazem a condição `x in conjuntoA and True`, que serão todos os elementos de A.

[Como funciona o operador 'in' no Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/221774/5878)

Para corrigir isso, você pode corrigir a condição:

```
x in conjuntoA and x in conjuntoB
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/KhcMny).

Perceba que é necessário repetir a parte `x in`. Porém, outra alternativa é utilizar o tipo `set` do Python:

```
a = set([2,4,6,7,10])
b = set([3,4,6,8,10,11])

print(a.intersection(b)) # {4, 6, 10}
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/cKgj5b).

Answer (score 2):

se vc esta precisando de operações entre conjuntos, e só usar set:

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
b = {0, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10}
intersecao = (a & b)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 2):

Este é um modo de fazer utilizando 1 for e 1 if apenas.

```
def intersecao(lista1, lista2):
    lista3 = []
    for n in lista1:
        if n in lista2:
            lista3.append(n)
    return lista3

# n percorre lista1
# if valida se n esta em lista2
# então faz append em lista3
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu arrisco códigos em Phyton mas não sou expert, então desculpe se errei algo na sintaxe, porém você poderia usar a seguinte lógica:

```
    def intersecao(conjuntoA, conjuntoB):
        inter = []
        for x in conjuntoA:
            for y in conjuntoB:
                if x == y:
                    inter.append(x)
        return inter

    a = [2,4,6,7,10]
    b = [3,4,6,8,10,11]
    print(intersecao(a,b))
```

Comment: Você pode simplificar seu código eliminando o segundo `for`. Ao invés de percorrer todo o conjunto B, pode fazer apenas `if x in conjuntoB`. Veja: https://ideone.com/B8iGI7

Answer (score 1):

Para se encontrar a `interseção` de **quaisquer** `dois` conjuntos podemos utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
def intersecao(conjuntoA, conjuntoB):
    inter = list(conjuntoA & conjuntoB)
    inter.sort()

    print(f'\033[32mA interseção entre os conjuntos A e B é: {inter}')


conja = list(map(int, input('Digite os elementos do Conjunto A: ').split()))
conjb = list(map(int, input('Digite os elementos do Conjunto B: ').split()))
a = set(conja)
b = set(conjb)
intersecao(a, b)
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/zhcznajb-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.

Quando este algoritmo é executado ele `solicita` a digitação de todos os elementos do conjunto `A`. Neste momento devemos digitar **todos** os elementos em **uma só linha** separados por **um espaço**.

A parir desse momento os valores são armazenados em uma `lista` e, em seguida, convertidos em `conjuntos`.

Depois nos é solicitado o elementos do conjunto `B`.

Em seguida é calculado a `interseção dos conjuntos`.

Em seguida, para melhorar a visibilidade dos resultados, o conjunto de interseções é convertido para `lista`, em seguida `ordenado` em forma crescente e, posteriormente `exibidos` em forma de lista.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que percebi você está testando num intervalo que  a linguagem já abstrai. Ou seja, o Python percorre sem a necessidade desse range ali, a não ser que precise de retornar um ponto específico dentro da lista:

```
a,b = [2,4,6,7,10],[3,4,6,8,10,11]
intersec = [i for i in b if i in a] ## Retorna o que for comum entre as duas.
```

Answer (score -3):

```
conjA = {"João", "José", "Descomplica", "USP"}
conjB = {'USP', "Descomplica", "PUC-RJ", "PUC-BA", "UFV"}

def Procurar(conjA, conjB):#define função para procurar interseccao
  interseccao = set(conjA.intersection(conjB)) ## utiliza o set para fazer a interseccao entre os dois itens da funcao
  return interseccao
  
print(Procurar (conjA, conjB)) #chama e imprime a funcao
```

Comment: Como ambos já são `set`'s, bastaria fazer `def Procurar(conjA, conjB):
  return conjA & conjB` (como já apontado em outras respostas)