# Verificar retorno da expressão "in" altera o resultado em Python

Tags: python, condição, python-internals

É sabido que para verificar se um determinado elemento não pertence a uma lista basta utilizar o operador `in`:

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

if 9 not in values:
    print("9 não pertence à lista.")
else:
    print("9 pertence à lista.")

# 9 não pertence à lista.
```

<sup>Veja funcionando em [Ideone](https://ideone.com/tKCur5) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Lpe8/1)</sup>

E que este operador retorna `True` quando o elemento pertence à lista em questão ou `False` caso contrário, podendo ser atribuído tal retorno à uma variável:

```
condition = 9 in values

print(condition) # False
```

<sup>Veja funcionando em [Ideone](https://ideone.com/obukgt) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/LpdT/0)</sup>

Podendo, no caso, utilizar a variável como a condição:

```
if condition == False:
    print("9 não pertence à lista.")
else:
    print("9 pertence à lista.")

# 9 não pertence à lista.
```

Porém, se utilizar a expressão com `in` direto nesta verificação, o resultado é alterado:

```
if 9 in values == False:
    print("9 não pertence à lista.")
else:
    print("9 pertence à lista.")

# 9 pertence à lista.
```

<sup>Veja funcionando em [Ideone](https://ideone.com/ZVxQ3J) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/LpfJ/0)</sup>

Nesta última sintaxe, o resultado é que 9 pertence à lista (mesmo não pertencendo).

Por que isso ocorre? Esse comportamento é o esperado do Python? Se sim, como ele analisa esta última expressão?

Comment: Criei a pergunta pois julguei ser uma situação no mínimo curiosa que poderia gerar confusão para iniciantes, principalmente quando vindo de outras linguagens, então é esperado que as respostas sejam mais completas possíveis.

Comment: A única coisa que me vem a cabeça é ordem de precedência. Se protejer o 9 in values com parênteses dá a mesma coisa?

Comment: @JoãoVictor Com parênteses produz o resultado esperado.

Comment: @JoãoVictor a resposta seria não e sim, respectivamente. O problema não é a ordem de precedência, mas se colocar os parenteses o resultado é o esperado.

Comment: O problema é que a ordem de precedência é que o operador == sempre é executado antes do operador in. É como se vc tentasse somar um número para depois dividir e não protejer a soma com parênteses ( a divisão ocorreria primeiro ). O que acontece  o codigo em questão é que ele verifica se values é false antes de executar "9 in values". O que faz com que a cláusula retorne true.

Comment: @JoãoVictor foi respondido isso já, mas a resposta foi excluída pois não é esse o problema. Se quiser, acesse o [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) que posso explicar melhor o motivo que não ser isso (para não estender a discussão aqui).

Comment: @JoãoVictor [**Veja a resposta apagada e os comentários**](https://imgur.com/a/90DdB).

Comment: O operador "==" não tem a mesma precedência do operador "in" não... Isso é para a sua primeira justificativa. A segunda sobre dar erro de tentar iterar por um booleano ainda não sei explicar. Mas vou procurar saber e respondo aqui.

Comment: @JoãoVictor Veja a [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) com a tabela de precedência.

Comment: Ah ok, foi usado python 3? Desculpe minha ignorância, testei em python 2.7.

Comment: @JoãoVictor [mesma coisa](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Comment: Realmente a documentação diz mesma ordem de precedência, mas se ficar testando prints com essas expressões você não chega a essa conclusão. Eu não li a documentação, mas imagino que tenha alguma exceção. Não sei explicar mais que isso. Caso alguém responda, irei voltar aqui para ler.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O que acontece aí é uma pequena confusão, talvez pelo costume com outras linguagens e pela forma pouco "evidente" desta expressão.

#### Um pouco sobre comparações

Em Python, diferentemente da maioria das linguagens que eu conheço, é possível ter expressões no formato `a < b < c`. Isso é muito comum na matemática e a interpretação desta expressão em Python se dá da mesma forma.

Por exemplo:

```
a = 2
b = 3
c = 4

print(a < b < c) 
# True
```

<sup>**Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Lq39)**</sup>

A expressão acima será avaliada como **`a < b and b < c`**.

Um pedacinho [da documentação que fala sobre isso](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> *(...) Also unlike C, expressions like `a < b < c` have the interpretation that is conventional in mathematics (...)*
>
> *(...) Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to **`x < y and y <= z`** (...)*

Em tradução livre:

> *(...) Também ao contrário de C, expressões como `a < b < c` têm a interpretação que é convencional na matemática (...)*
>
> *(...) Comparações podem ser encadeadas arbitrariamente, por exemplo: `x < y <= z` é equivalente a **`x < y and y <= z`***

#### O que acontece no seu código

A primeira coisa que vem à cabeça quando se vê a expressão **`9 in values == False`** é que o interpretador deverá avaliar o resultado de `9 in values` e depois disto, comparar com `False`.

Na verdade, a expressão acaba caindo no caso acima e é avaliada para **`9 in values and values == False`**.

O que, por sua vez, é avaliada para **`False and True`** e depois disso para **`False`**

Por exemplo:

```
a = 'ana'
b = 'nana'
c = 'banana'

print(a in b in c) 
# True
```

<sup>**Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@jfbueno/ptso241769)**</sup>

Answer (score 10):

Sim, este comportamento é o esperado do Python justamente pela forma como ele analisará a expressão, **mas tal comportamento não tem relação alguma com a ordem de precedência dos operadores**.

O que ocorre é que no Python existe um açúcar sintático para expressões booleanas quando utilizados dois operadores como no problema citado. A expressão real analisada pelo Python será, na verdade, os dois operadores executados de forma independente, repetindo o operando central, unindo os resultados por uma operação lógica `and`. Em outras palavras, uma expressão como `A <op1> B <op2> C`, sendo `A`, `B` e `C` os operandos e `<op1>` e `<op2>` os operadores, a expressão analisada será `(A <op1> B) and (B <op2> C)`. Neste caso, ao fazer:

```
if 9 in values == False:
    print("9 não pertence à lista.")
else:
    print("9 pertence à lista.")
```

O que acontece, de fato, será:

```
if (9 in values) and (values == False):
    print("9 não pertence à lista.")
else:
    print("9 pertence à lista.")
```

Onde `9 in values` retorna falso e `values == False` retorna falso; portanto, o resultado final será, também, falso, executando o bloco em `else`.

Neste caso em especial realmente o resultado parece ser bastante estranho, mas este açúcar sintático é especialmente útil, por exemplo, para verificar se um determinado valor pertence a um intervalo:

```
if 0 < x < 10:
    print("x está entre 0 e 10")
else:
    print("x é menor que 1 ou maior que 9")
```

Tal código seria o equivalente a fazer:

```
if 0 < x and x < 10:
    print("x está entre 0 e 10")
else:
    print("x é menor que 1 ou maior que 9")
```

Ou ainda equivalente à forma tradicional:

```
if x > 0 and x < 10:
    print("x está entre 0 e 10")
else:
    print("x é menor que 1 ou maior que 9")
```

Esse comportamento explica o porquê da primeira forma apresentada na pergunta ser a ideal em Python (modo [*pythonico*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/5878)):

```
if 9 not in values:
    print("9 não pertence à lista.")
else:
    print("9 pertence à lista.")
```

## TL;DR

Uma forma de verificar esse comportamento é analisar o *bytecode* gerado pelo CPython. Para tal, podemos utilizar a biblioteca nativa [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/dis.html). Para fins de simplificação, consideraremos uma expressão um pouco mais simples, que reproduz o mesmo comportamento do problema abordado:

```
a < b < c
```

Onde tentaremos mostrar que a expressão analisada será `(a < b) and (b < c)`.

Obtemos a análise do *bytecode* desta expressão fazendo:

```
import dis

print(dis.dis("a < b < c"))
```

No qual o resultado será:

```
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              4 DUP_TOP
              6 ROT_THREE
              8 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             10 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    18
             12 LOAD_NAME                2 (c)
             14 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   18 ROT_TWO
             20 POP_TOP
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

Na própria documentação podemos obter os detalhes de cada operação:

1. [`LOAD_NAME`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_NAME) coloca o valor associado ao nome `a` na pilha;
2. [`LOAD_NAME`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_NAME) coloca o valor associado ao nome `b` na pilha;
3. [`DUP_TOP`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/dis.html#opcode-DUP_TOP) duplica a referência no topo da pilha;
4. [`ROT_THREE`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/dis.html#opcode-ROT_THREE) sobe o segundo e terceiro valores da pilha uma posição e move o topo para a posição 3;
5. [`COMPARE_OP`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/dis.html#opcode-COMPARE_OP) executa a operação `<` entre os dois valores no topo da pilha, removendo-os, e adiciona o resultado;
6. [`JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/dis.html#opcode-JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP) define um desvio condicional com base no valor do topo da pilha: se o valor for falso, a execução salta para a linha indicada por `>>` (item 10 desta lista), caso contrário, o valor do topo da pilha é removido e a execução continua;
7. [`LOAD_NAME`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_NAME) coloca o valor associado ao nome `c` na pilha;
8. [`COMPARE_OP`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/dis.html#opcode-COMPARE_OP) executa a operação `<` entre os dois valores no topo da pilha, removendo-os, e adiciona o resultado;
9. [`RETURN_VALUE`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/dis.html#opcode-RETURN_VALUE) retorna o valor do topo da pilha;
10. [`ROT_TWO`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/dis.html#opcode-ROT_TWO) permuta os dois valores no topo da pilha;
11. [`POP_TOP`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/dis.html#opcode-POP_TOP) descarta o topo da pilha;
12. [`RETURN_VALUE`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/dis.html#opcode-RETURN_VALUE) retorna o valor do topo da pilha;

O salto que pode ocorrer entre os itens 6 e 10 é o que chamamos de *curto-circuito* de uma expressão lógica.

**Analisando o *bytecode* do problema da pergunta**

Para o caso da pergunta, vamos considerar a expressão:

```
9 in values == False
```

O *bytecode* gerado é praticamente idêntico ao anterior (o que mostra que a expressão anterior realmente reproduz o mesmo comportamento):

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (9)
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (values)
              4 DUP_TOP
              6 ROT_THREE
              8 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             10 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    18
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 (False)
             14 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   18 ROT_TWO
             20 POP_TOP
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

> As únicas diferenças, de fato, são que para os valores `9` e `False` são executadas as operações `LOAD_CONST`, por serem constantes, e não mais `LOAD_NAME`, referente à variáveis.

Executando, temos:

1. Adiciona o valor constante 9 à pilha;

   ```
     | Stack
   --+--------
   1 | 9
   --+--------
   2 |
   --+--------
   3 |
   ```
2. Adiciona o valor `values` à pilha;

   ```
     | Stack
   --+--------
   1 | 9
   --+--------
   2 | values
   --+--------
   3 |
   ```
3. Duplica o valor do topo da pilha;

   ```
     | Stack
   --+--------
   1 | 9
   --+--------
   2 | values
   --+--------
   3 | values
   ```
4. Sobe uma posição o segundo e terceiro valores, movendo o topo para a terceira posição;

   ```
     | Stack
   --+--------
   1 | values
   --+--------
   2 | 9
   --+--------
   3 | values
   ```
5. Executa o operador `in` entre os dois valores do topo `9 in values`, empilhando o resultado;

   ```
     | Stack
   --+--------
   1 | values
   --+--------
   2 | False
   --+--------
   3 |
   ```
6. Se o topo da pilha for falso, pula a execução (pilha permanece inalterada);
7. Permuta os dois valores do topo da pilha;

   ```
     | Stack
   --+--------
   1 | False
   --+--------
   2 | values
   --+--------
   3 |
   ```
8. Descarta o valor do topo da pilha;

   ```
     | Stack
   --+--------
   1 | False
   --+--------
   2 | 
   --+--------
   3 |
   ```
9. Retorna o valor do topo da pilha `False`;

Assim é possível perceber claramente o motivo do `else` ser executado no problema e que o segundo operador, `==`, sequer é analisado, devido ao curto-circuito que ocorre na expressão lógica.

Vale notar que, mesmo que não exista explicitamente o operador `and` sendo executado, o comportamento "*retorne o primeiro operando se for false, se não retorna o segundo*" é o comportamento natural do operador `and`, por isso que é dito que a expressão é avaliada como se existisse `and` entre as expressões.

**Leituras interessantes**

[Como funciona o operador 'in' no Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/221774/5878)

[Operações lógicas em Python 2.7](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214296/5878)