# Iniciar variável numérica com valor nulo no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while

Navegando pelo site da Python Brasil, resolvi fazer o exercício 1 da lista Estrutura de Repetição:

"Faça um programa que peça uma nota, entre zero e dez. Mostre uma mensagem caso o valor 
seja inválido e continue pedindo até que o usuário informe um valor válido."

```
nota = ""
while nota < 0 or nota > 10:
    nota = float(input("Digite uma nota de 0 a 10: "))
    print "Nota inválida, digite apenas uma nota de 0 a 10."

print("Nota: %.1f" %nota)
```

Após tentar resolver, encontrei também esta solução desenvolvida em Python2 ao reescrevê-la para Python 3 me deparei com o problema: o Py3 não faz a comparação do `while` quando a variável global nota tem valor `null`

```
# Python 3
nota = float(None)
while nota < 0 or nota > 10:
    nota = float(input("Digite uma nota de 0 a 10: "))
    print('Nota inválida, digite apenas uma nota de 0 a 10.')

print('Nota: {:.1f}'.format(nota))
```

Como poderia solucionar este problema ainda utilizando o Python 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu particularmente não gosto da solução de ler o valor antes do laço e lê-lo novamente dentro do laço. São linhas de códigos iguais, que se transformam em dois lugares para editar caso a aplicação mude e o código fica redundante. Como não tempos como saber quantas iterações serão necessárias para ler um valor válido, nada mais justo que criar um *loop* infinito. Também não sabemos se o valor lido do usuário será numérico, então devemos nos atentar à exceção que pode ser disparada pelo inicializador de `float` ao tentar converter o valor. E tendo vista que iremos tratar uma exceção, nada melhor que disparar a mesma exceção caso o valor não esteja no intervalo desejado, assim conseguindo concentrar o tratamento de *erro* em apenas um lugar.

Veja um exemplo:

```
while True:
    try:
        nota = float(input("Digite uma nota entre 0 e 10: "))
        if not 0 < nota < 10:
            raise ValueError("A nota deve ser um valor entre 0 e 10")
    except ValueError as error:
        print(error)
    else:
        break
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/NavyDirectPuppy)</sup>

O bloco `else` do `try` será executado apenas se nenhuma exceção for disparada, indicando que o valor lido é numérico e está no intervalo desejado, parando o laço; caso contrário, o laço continua a ser executado, até ler um valor válido.

---

No seu código, o erro se dá por tentar converter um valor nulo em *float*. Isto não faz sentido no Python: ou é um valor nulo ou é um *float*. O que você poderia é iniciar com um valor que você tem certeza que é inválido para o intervalo, garantindo que o *loop* seja executado.

```
nota = 0
while not 0 < nota < 10:
    nota = float(input("Digite uma nota de 0 a 10: "))
    if not 0 < nota < 10:
        print('Nota inválida, digite apenas uma nota de 0 a 10.')

print('Nota: {:.1f}'.format(nota))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/LightbluePristineBlackfly)</sup>

Inicializando a variável com 0, você garante que o laço será executado, lendo o valor do usuário, porém cai no que eu comentei no início da resposta: você precisará fazer a mesma condição dentro do laço, repetindo código. A captura da exceção é primordial para o funcionamento correto do programa, pois da maneira que está, se o usuário digitar um texto, seu programa terminará com o lançamento da exceção. Com o bloco `try/except` você previne isso.

Comment: Anderson, agradeço suas respostas. Gostei bastante da com tratamento de erros. Apenas fiquei um pouco confuso com a linha:
             if not 0 < nota < 10:
Dá a entender que 0 não pode ser menor que nota e nota não pode ser menor que 10. Poderia, por gentileza, me explicar um pouco mais sobre esta estrutura? Ou como é chamado isso para eu pesquisar mais a respeito?

Comment: @LucasBraga No Python, a expressão `0 < nota < 10` é equivalente à `0 < nota and nota < 10`, que produz o mesmo resultado que `nota > 0 and nota < 10`, ou seja, retorna *true* se `nota` pertence ao intervalo e *False*, caso contrário. Fazendo `if not 0 < nota < 10` estou verificando se o valor de `nota` não pertence ao intervalo.

Comment: A explicação detalhada de como funciona pode ser encontrada nesta pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241769/5878. Embora a pergunta pareça ser diferente, as respostas abordam exatamente esta situação.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema, solicitando a nota antes do *while*  e dentro do corpo do *while* solicitando novamente, para caso o valor estiver fora da faixa especificada.

```
nota = float(input("Digite uma nota de 0 a 10: "))
while nota < 0 or nota > 10:

    print('Nota inválida, digite apenas uma nota de 0 a 10.')
    nota = float(input("Digite uma nota de 0 a 10: "))

print('Nota: {:.1f}'.format(nota))
```

Mas ainda assim minha dúvida referente a variável com valor null repercute. Alguém sabe me explicar como isso funciona no Python 3?

Answer (score -1):

Retirei a variável do while e o programa reproduziu corretamente, pedindo uma nota e dando o valor da que digitei, ficou assim:

```
nota = float(input("Digite uma nota de 0 a 10: "))
while nota < 0 or nota > 10:

print('Nota inválida, digite apenas uma nota de 0 a 10.')

print('Nota: {:.1f}'.format(nota))
```

Comment: Agradeço Leandro, mas no seu código o programa só funciona se o usuário digitar a nota entre a faixa estabelecida(0 a 10) caso contrário o programa fica em loop infinito e não deixa o usuário tentar digitar novamente.