# Por que ao inserir um valor em uma lista ele se torna None?

Tags: python, lista

```
valores = []

valor1 = valores.append(int(input('Valor 1: ')))
valor2 = valores.append(int(input('Valor 2: ')))

if valor1 in valores > 0:
  print(valor1, 'é positivo')
else:
  print(valor1, 'é negativo')

if valor2 in valores > 0:
  print(valor2, 'é positivo')
else:
  print(valor2, 'é negativo')
```

Ao executar o código, inserimos os dois valores e no final ambos são negativos pois são "none":

```
Valor 1: 10
Valor 2: 20
None é negativo
None é negativo
```

Queria entender por que os valores estão retornando none, o que está errado.

Comment: Você está fazendo `valor1 = valores.append(...)`; o retorno da função `append` é `None`.

Comment: Sobre a sua condição `valor1 in valores > 0`, leia essa discussão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241769/5878

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece porque [`append` retorna `None`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16641119).

Se quer ler os valores e guardá-los na lista, faça esses passos separadamente:

```
valores = []

# primeiro lê os valores
valor1 = int(input('Valor 1: '))
valor2 = int(input('Valor 2: '))

# depois insere na lista
valores.append(valor1)
valores.append(valor2)

# ou, se quiser, crie a lista diretamente com os valores
valores = [ valor1, valor2 ]
```

Outro ponto é que isso não faz sentido:

```
if valor2 in valores > 0:
```

Como o valor já foi inserido na lista, não precisaria verificar se ele está na lista. E de qualquer forma, não é assim que verifica se o valor é maior que zero (na verdade, [esta expressão não faz o que você está imaginando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241769/5878)). Bastaria fazer apenas:

```
if valor1 > 0:
  print(valor1, 'é positivo')
else:
  print(valor1, 'é negativo')

if valor2 > 0:
  print(valor2, 'é positivo')
else:
  print(valor2, 'é negativo')
```

Comment: valeu amigo!! realmente foi falta de atenção minha, muito obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Oi, sua atribuição em:

```
valor1 = valores.append(int(input('Valor 1: ')))
valor2 = valores.append(int(input('Valor 2: ')))
```

Está errada, nas variavéis `valor1` e `valor2` não há nada, logo o Python trata como `None`. A sua lógica na condicional (`if`/`else`) também tá estranha.

Versão "corrigida"

```
valor1 = int(input('Valor 1: '))
valor2 = int(input('Valor 2: '))

if valor1 > 0:
  print(valor1, 'é positivo')
else:
  print(valor1, 'é negativo')

if valor2 > 0:
  print(valor2, 'é positivo')
else:
  print(valor2, 'é negativo')
```

Se precisar mesmo usar listas:

```
arr = []
arr.append(int(input('Valor 1: ')))
arr.append(int(input('Valor 2: ')))

for i in arr:
   if i > 0:  # como pode ver, não há tratamento para valor == 0 
      print(f'{i} é positivo.')
   else:
      print(f'{i} é negativo.')
```

Comment: valeu amigo!! falta de atenção minha, muito obrigado