# Testar com if se uma variável tem um ou outro valor?

Tags: python

Eu quero verificar se uma string é um dos valores indicados:

```
if valor == "aprovado\n" or "aprovado":
    # faz algo com valor
```

Mas quando faço assim, ele **sempre** entra no `if`, independente do valor - mesmo se a string tiver um texto completamente diferente.

O que está errado?

Comment: Só pra simplificar pra quem veio aqui buscando testar duas condições de igualdade com `or`: a construção seria `if valor == "umacoisa" or valor == "outracoisa":` - Compensa ver a resposta dada, se quiser entender a razão (e conhecera a alternativa do `in` quando os vários valores forem comparados com a mesma variável).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A construção da sua condição está errada:

```
if valor == "aprovado\n" or "aprovado":
    ...
```

Mas antes de começar, é preciso saber que uma *string* não vazia é considerada como um valor verdadeiro no Python (*truthy value*). Isto é, um valor que se convertido para *booleano* seria `True`.

- [O que são os valores truthy e falsy?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271693/5878)

Desta forma, a condição `if "foo"` sempre será satisfeita, pois seria o mesmo que `if True`.

Analisando a sua condição:

```
if valor == "aprovado\n" or "aprovado":
    ...
```

Vamos supor que `valor` possua o valor `"aprovado\n"`. Primeiro, o interpretador irá avaliar a comparação `valor == "aprovado\n"`, que retornará `True`, ficando assim:

```
if True or "aprovado":
    ...
```

Essa condição sempre será satisfeita, portanto, quando valer `"aprovado\n"` ele entra na condicional.

Vamos supor agora que `valor` possua o valor `"aprovado"`. Primeiro, o interpretador irá avaliar a comparação `valor == "aprovado\n"`, que retornará `False`, ficando assim:

```
if False or "aprovado":
    ...
```

Essa condição sempre será satisfeita, pois `"aprovado"` é verdadeiro, portanto, quando valer `"aprovado"` ele entra na condicional.

Finalmente, vamos supor que `valor` valha qualquer valor diferente dos outros já considerados. Primeiro, o interpretador irá avaliar a comparação `valor == "aprovado\n"`, que retornará `False`, ficando assim:

```
if False or "aprovado":
    ...
```

Essa condição sempre será satisfeita, pois `"aprovado"` é verdadeiro, portanto, quando valer `"aprovado"` ele entra na condicional.

Concluindo:

- Quando `valor` vale `"aprovado\n"` entra no `if`;
- Quando `valor` vale `"aprovado"` entra no `if`;
- Quando `valor` vale qualquer outro valor entra no `if`;

Ou seja, sua condição não depende do valor de `valor` e poderia ser substituída por:

```
if True:
    ...
```

Porém, como você quer verificar se `valor` possui um dos dois elementos, use o operador `in`:

```
if valor in {"aprovado\n", "aprovado"}:
    ...
```

Ou ainda melhor, **neste caso específico**, como a diferença é apenas o caractere `\n` no final, basta removê-lo antes da comparação:

```
valor = valor.strip()
if valor == "aprovado":
    ...
```

A função `strip()` irá remover o `\n` do final, podendo comparar apenas com um valor.

A forma como o Python lida com os operadores lógicos foi discutida nesta pergunta:

- [Operações lógicas em Python 2.7](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214296/5878)

---

Obs: isso não vale somente para strings. Conforme a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), qualquer valor, quando avaliado em um contexto *booleano*, pode ser considerado `True` ou `False`. Sendo assim, a expressão:

```py
if valor == x or y:
```

Está verificando duas condições:

- se `valor` é igual a `x`, ou
- `y` (não está comparando com `valor`, está apenas avaliando o valor de `y`, que pode ser considerado verdadeiro ou falso de acordo com as regras já citadas)

Para verificar se o valor é `x` ou `y`, aí deve-se usar uma das opções acima: `valor == x or valor == y` ou `valor in {x, y}` - sendo esta última mais indicada quando há muitos valores.

Comment: Deu certo! Eu ainda não conhecia a função strip(), vou anotar pra não esquecer. Muito obrigado.