# Erro de condição do PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Estou tendo erro de condição no PyCharm. Estava funcionando normalmente minutos atrás. Já fechei o programa, porem não resolveu.

```
valorProduto = float(input('Qual é o valor do produto de compra? R$ '))
modoPagamento = input('Deseja parcelar ou pagar à vista? ')

if modoPagamento == 'à vista' or 'À vista':
    desconto = valorProduto - (valorProduto * 20 / 100)
    print('Certo! Nesse caso, você recebe-rá 20% de desconto.')
    print('O novo preço do produto é R${:.2f}'.format(desconto))

elif modoPagamento == 'parcelar' or 'parcela':
    print('Certo! Pagamento parcelado. Segue abaixo tabela de parcelamentos:')
    print('=' * 10, 'Tabela', '=' * 10, '\n2 à 3 parcelas, acréscimo de 5%.\n4 à 6 parcelas, acréscimo de 10%.'
                                      '\n7 à 10 parcelas, acréscimo de 15%.\n11 parcelas ou mais, acréscimo de 25%.')
    parcela = int(input('Deseja fazer em quantas parcelas? '))

    if parcela <= 3:
        valorParcela = ((valorProduto / parcela) + ((valorProduto * 5) / 100))
        preçoFinal = valorParcela + valorParcela
        print('Certo! {} vezes. Nesse caso, você receberá um acréscimo de 5% sobre o valor do produto.\nTotalizando'
              ' {} parcelas de R${:.2f} com o preço final do produto de R${:.2f}'.format(parcela, parcela, valorParcela,
                                                                                         preçoFinal))

    elif parcela <= 6:
        valorParcela = (valorProduto / parcela) + ((valorProduto * 10) / 100)
        preçoFinal = valorParcela + valorParcela
        print('Certo! {} vezes. Nesse caso, você receberá um acréscimo de 10% sobre o valor do produto.\nTotalizando'
              ' {} parcelas de R${:.2f} com o preço final do produto de R${:.2f}'.format(parcela, parcela, valorParcela,
                                                                                         preçoFinal))

else:
    print('Modo de pagamento inválido!')
```

Comment: Seu problema parece ser o mesmo que esse: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/353470/112052

Comment: Segui as dicas do Anderson Carlos Woss, mas não consegui resolver o problema ainda. É como eu comentei. Tempinho atrás estava funcionando normalmente if e elif com outro programa. agora parou de funcionar em qualquer programa no que criar. em qualquer newfile.

Comment: @Jones Se o seu problema foi solucionado, não deixe de marcar a resposta como aceita.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dias atrás eu tive dúvida parecida e o Anderson Woss me respondeu brilhantemente neste post aqui: [Dificuldades com uso do IF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/353470/dificuldades-com-uso-do-if).

Seu problema é basicamente o mesmo que o meu. Copiei o seu código, colei aqui e coloquei pra rodar, de início ele sempre entrava no `if` do à vista, mesmo que eu escolhesse a opção de parcelamento, conforme imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então fiz alterações na seguinte linha de código:

```
if modoPagamento == 'à vista' or 'À vista':
```

Mudei para:

```
if modoPagamento in {'à vista','À vista'}:
```

E, por consequência, também fiz alteração nesta linha:

```
elif modoPagamento == 'parcelar' or 'parcela':
```

Mudei para:

```
elif modoPagamento in {'parcelar','parcela'}:
```

Agora o programa já me apresenta as opções de parcelamento caso eu escolha a opção de  pagar parcelado, conforme mostra a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Reparei também que seu programa está com um erro quando o usuário escolhe a opção de pagar parcelado. Repare na imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que eu optei em pagar em 3 vezes um produto que custa 1000 reais e mesmo com o acréscimo de 5% devido ao parcelamento o preço do produto final ficou em 766,67. Isto ocorreu devido a um erro na construção matemática da solução e não exatamente devido a um erro no programa, por isso não vou me preocupar em corrigir, mas repare que poderia ser feito de uma forma mais sucinta, conforme mostro a seguir:

```
if parcela <= 3:
    valorProduto = valorProduto * 1.05 #Multiplicando por 1,05 você já aumenta o preço final do produto em 5%
    valorParcela = (valorProduto / parcela)
    print('Certo! {} vezes. Nesse caso, você receberá um acréscimo de 5% sobre o valor do produto.\nTotalizando {} parcelas de R${:.2f} com o preço final do produto de R${:.2f}'.format(parcela, parcela, valorParcela, valorProduto))
```

Seu código final ficou assim:

```
valorProduto = float(input('Qual é o valor do produto de compra? R$ '))
modoPagamento = input('Deseja parcelar ou pagar à vista? ')

if modoPagamento in {'à vista','À vista'}:
    desconto = valorProduto - (valorProduto * 20 / 100)
    print('Certo! Nesse caso, você receberá 20% de desconto.')
    print('O novo preço do produto é R${:.2f}'.format(desconto))

elif modoPagamento in {'parcelar','parcela'}:
    print('Certo! Pagamento parcelado. Segue abaixo tabela de parcelamentos:')
    print('=' * 10, 'Tabela', '=' * 10, '\n2 à 3 parcelas, acréscimo de 5%.\n4 à 6 parcelas, acréscimo de 10%.'
                                  '\n7 à 10 parcelas, acréscimo de 15%.\n11 parcelas ou mais, acréscimo de 25%.')
    parcela = int(input('Deseja fazer em quantas parcelas? '))

    if parcela <= 3:
        valorProduto = valorProduto * 1.05
        valorParcela = valorProduto / parcela
        print('Certo! {} vezes. Nesse caso, você receberá um acréscimo de 5% sobre o valor do produto.\nTotalizando {} parcelas de R${:.2f} com o preço final do produto de R${:.2f}'.format(parcela, parcela, valorParcela, valorProduto))

    elif parcela <= 6:
        valorProduto = valorProduto * 1.10
        valorParcela = valorProduto / parcela
        print('Certo! {} vezes. Nesse caso, você receberá um acréscimo de 10% sobre o valor do produto.\nTotalizando {} parcelas de R${:.2f} com o preço final do produto de R${:.2f}'.format(parcela, parcela, valorParcela, valorProduto))

    elif parcela <= 10:
        valorProduto = valorProduto * 1.15
        valorParcela = valorProduto / parcela
        print('Certo! {} vezes. Nesse caso, você receberá um acréscimo de 15% sobre o valor do produto.\nTotalizando {} parcelas de R${:.2f} com o preço final do produto de R${:.2f}'.format(parcela, parcela, valorParcela, valorProduto))

    elif parcela > 10:
        valorProduto = valorProduto * 1.25
        valorParcela = valorProduto / parcela
        print('Certo! {} vezes. Nesse caso, você receberá um acréscimo de 25% sobre o valor do produto.\nTotalizando {} parcelas de R${:.2f} com o preço final do produto de R${:.2f}'.format(parcela, parcela, valorParcela, valorProduto))
```

Espero ter conseguido te ajudar.