# Ler dados com input e escrever as linhas lidas em um arquivo

Tags: python

Eu estou tentando criar um programa que quando eu der uma entrada ele vai criando uma lista dentro de um arquivo, mas quando eu tento fazer isso ele adiciona minhas entradas em uma linha única e não uma embaixo da outra.

Deve haver um comando para isso, como posso fazer para arrumar isso?

```
arquivo = open('contas', 'w')
def adicionar():
    while True:
        a = input('\nO que quer adicionar?: ')
        arquivo.write(a)
        if a == '':
            break
adicionar()
arquivo.close
```

Answer (score 3):

Basta você adicionar a quebra de linha na string, ao passá-la para o método `write`:

```
with open('contas', 'w') as arquivo:
    while True:
        a = input('\nO que quer adicionar?: ')
        arquivo.write(a + "\n") # <-- aqui
        if not a:
            break
```

O `"\n"` corresponde à quebra de linha. Repare também que usei `with`, que já [fecha o arquivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/112052) automaticamente ao final da execução, mesmo que ocorra algum erro.

Também removi a função `adicionar`, que me parece desnecessária aqui. Da forma que foi feita, ela só pode ser chamada depois que o arquivo estiver aberto, e mesmo assim a variável só poderá se chamar `arquivo` - enfim, se quer uma função, ou ela deveria receber o arquivo como parâmetro, e deveria verificar se ele está aberto, ou então a função deveria receber o nome do arquivo como parâmetro e fazer tudo dentro dela (abrir, escrever, fechar). Mas para um programa pequeno como esse, que só vai fazer isso, acho um exagero criar esta função.

Repare também no final: `if not a` verifica se a string é vazia. Esta é uma outra forma de verificar, já que uma string vazia é considerada um valor falso (*falsy value*) - leia mais sobre isso [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/353481/112052).

---

Outro detalhe é que este código sempre adiciona a quebra de linha no final, para todas as linhas - inclusive para a string vazia. Ou seja, o arquivo terá duas linhas em branco no final (uma relativa à última string não-vazia digitada, e outra relativa à string vazia).

Se quiser evitar isso, basta verificar se a string é vazia **antes** de escrever:

```
with open('contas', 'w') as arquivo:
    while True:
        a = input('\nO que quer adicionar?: ')
        if not a: # se a linha for vazia, sai e não escreve ela no arquivo
            break
        arquivo.write(a + "\n")
```

Agora o arquivo só vai ter uma linha vazia no final, referente à última string não-vazia digitada. Mas se quiser eliminar esta linha também, então o jeito é ir guardando tudo em uma lista e juntar tudo no final:

```
lista = []
while True:
    a = input('\nO que quer adicionar?: ')
    if not a:  # se a linha for vazia, sai e não adiciona na lista
        break
    lista.append(a)

with open('contas', 'w') as arquivo:
    arquivo.write("\n".join(lista))
```

Agora eu crio uma lista e vou adicionando apenas as strings não-vazias nela. No final, junto tudo com o método [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), usando a quebra de linha como o "juntador" (o que vai ficar entre cada elemento da lista). Assim, a última string não-vazia não terá a quebra de linha adicionada depois dela.

---

Outra opção é, em vez de `arquivo.write`, usar a função [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#print), passando o arquivo como parâmetro (já que o `print`, por *default*, adiciona a quebra de linha no final):

```
with open('contas', 'w') as arquivo:
    while True:
        a = input('\nO que quer adicionar?: ')
        print(a, file=arquivo)
        if not a:
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente isto:

```
arquivo = open('contas', 'w')
def adicionar():
    while True:
        print("O que quer adicionar?: ")
        a="\n".join(iter(input,""))
        arquivo.write(a)
        if a == '':
            break
adicionar()
arquivo.close
```

Recomendo a leitura:

1. [Iteradores em Python](http://turing.com.br/material/ppqsp/2011/ppqsp_t0a2.pdf)
2. [Python String join()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/join)(Em inglês)