# O Python não está lendo uma condicional dentro de uma condicional

Tags: python

Olá, estou fazendo um joguinho de perguntas e na parte que o player erra eu quero colocar uma opção de tentar novamente ou não porém o Python não lê ou executa a condicional dentro do else. Pensei no código assim:

```py
while True:
    frase1 = input('"Lastimável discípulo, que não ultrapassa o mestre."\nQUEM DISSE ISSO?\na)Leonardo da Vinci\nb)Meu pai\nc)Seu pai\nd)Steve Jobs\n')

    if frase1 == ('a' or 'Leonardo da Vinci' or 'leonardo da vinci'):
        print('Parabéns!\nVocê acertou!')
        pontuacao += 1
        break

    elif frase1 == ('b'):
        print('NÃO FALA NO MEU PAI!\n')

    else:
        falha1 = input('Você errou.\nTentar novamente?\nSim ou Não. ')

        if falha1 == ('Sim' or 's'):
            print('Recomeça o jogo!\n')

        elif falha1 == ('Não' or 'Nao' or 'n'):
            print('Obrigado por jogar.')
            quit()
```

Comment: Duplicata de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/353470/5878

Comment: Mas qual o erro?

Comment: Opa, não entendi muito bem como esse post que você me mandou possa me ajudar. Visto que o problema não está na primeira condicional e sim na condicional else-if

Comment: @luczin Então tente [edit] sua pergunta e explicar qual problema está enfrentando

Comment: O erro está em que o python não reconhece a segunda condicional, quando dou o run e chego na parte do sim ou não, ao colocar sim ou não ele simplesmente repete em vez de executar o que foi pedido.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, espero que possam compreender melhor agora,

Comment: Praticamente todas as condições que você fez estão erradas e nesse link eu mostro o porquê (e como corrigir);

Comment: @Woss eu tô tentando entender como aplicar o que você me passou no meu projeto; Poderia me dar um help? Eu comecei a utilizar o Python ontem.

Comment: @Woss eu vi onde errei desta vez e consegui acertar. Muito obrigado. Obrigado aos demais também.