# Duvida no laço de repetição WHILE PYTHON

Tags: python

Minha dúvida eh, no laço de repetição while, na LINHA 27 quando eu escolho uma opção que não seja "1" ou "2" aparece Argumento inválido. tente novamente. uma vez e ja vai direto para a repetição do codigo para o jogador escolher cara ou coroa. sendo que, era para ele repetir o laço " escolha a opção 1 ou 2 ".

Alguma luz? obs. sou iniciante nesse mundo hahaha.

```
from random import choice # Choice será usado para fazer a escolha aleatória
from time import sleep # Sleep será usado para determinar um delay X entre um comando e outro.
 
print('~' * 27)
print('Bem vindo ao Cara ou Coroa')
print('~' * 27)

count = 0
while count == 0:
    moeda = ['Cara', 'Coroa']
    moeda = choice(moeda) # Escolha da moeda
    jogador = str(input('Cara ou Coroa? '))
    if jogador == moeda: # Se jogador for igual a moeda, vencedor = JOGADOR
        vencedor = 'jogador'
        print(vencedor)
    else: # Se não, vencedor = COMPUTADOR
        vencedor = 'computador'
        print(vencedor)

    print('=-' * 6)
    print('FIM DE JOGO!')
    print('=-' * 6)
    continuar = int(input('[1] SIM\n[2] NÃO\nVocê deseja continuar? '))
    if continuar == 1:
        continue
    elif continuar != 1 and 2:
        print('Argumento inválido. tente novamente.')
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Deveria ser `elif continuar == 2`. Não tem porque testar se é diferente de 1, porque no `if` vc já testa se é igual - ou seja, se chegou no `elif`, é porque com certeza não é 1 (senão teria entrado no `if`). E fazer `and 2` é um erro, explicado em mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/353470/112052)

Comment: Dito isso, talvez seja melhor separar em uma função específica pra ler a opção de continuar, fica menos confuso do que um loop dentro do outro (que foi sugerido abaixo): https://ideone.com/iIxWFl

Answer (score -2):

Teria que colocar outro while dentro desse while pra forçar a escolha, dai esse segundo while iria cuidar dessas condições, caso o jogador escolhesse continuar, ele voltaria ao while normal,  caso contrario o count receberia um valor diferente de 0 e terminaria... Bem, eu também sou novo, mas espero ter ajudado..
`

```
x = 0
count = 0
while count == 0:
    x = 0 #Aqui zeramos x pra não fechar o laço seguinte logo no inicio
    moeda = ['Cara', 'Coroa']
    moeda = choice(moeda) # Escolha da moeda
    jogador = str(input('Cara ou Coroa? '))
    if jogador == moeda: # Se jogador for igual a moeda, vencedor = JOGADOR
        vencedor = 'jogador'
        print(vencedor)
    else: # Se não, vencedor = COMPUTADOR
        vencedor = 'computador'
        print(vencedor)
    while x != 1:
        print('=-' * 6)
        print('FIM DE JOGO!')
        print('=-' * 6)        
        match input('[1] SIM\n[2] NÃO\nVocê deseja continuar? '):
            case '1': #Caso seja 1 x ganha 1 e volta laço normal
                x = 1
            case '2':
                x = 1 # Caso seja 2 x ganha 1, mas também count ganha 1
                count = 1 #Isso encerra o laço atual e o anterior
            case _: #Mas caso seja qualquer outra coisa ele printa..
                print("Argumento invalido, tente novamente!")
```

´