# Verificar números mágicos (aqueles cuja raiz quadrada é um número primo) dentro de um intervalo

Tags: python

Gostaria de saber porque não dá certo.

```
import math
#Se a divisão do numero der um primo, o número é mágico

is_magic = []
for n in range(8, 27):
    cont = 0

if pow(n,(1/2)) == 2 or 3 or 5 or 7:
    cont += 1
    is_magic.append(n)

print(is_magic) #Resposta  deveria ser 9 e 25
```

Answer (score 4):

Isso já foi detalhado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214307/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/353481/112052), mas basicamente, ao fazer:

```
if algumacoisa == 2 or 3
```

Na verdade as duas condições analisadas são `algumacoisa == 2` e `3` (apenas o valor `3`). E para o segundo caso (apenas o `3`), valem as regras do [*Truth Value Testing*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), nas quais qualquer objeto pode ser testado em um contexto *booleano*. No caso de números, apenas o zero é considerado falso, e qualquer outro valor é verdadeiro. Sendo assim, a condição "apenas o `3`" é considerado `True`. E como você está usando o operador `or` (que é verdadeiro se qualquer uma das condições for `True`), então sempre vai entrar neste `if`.

Então você pode fazer como indicado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/466740/112052) (`if valor == 2 or valor == 3 or valor == 5 or valor == 7:`), ou se quiser pode guardar os valores válidos em uma lista e usar o operador `in` para verificar se o valor é um dos que estão na lista:

```
import math

primos = [2, 3, 5, 7]
is_magic = []
for n in range(8, 27):
    if math.sqrt(n) in primos:
        is_magic.append(n)

print(is_magic) # [9, 25]
```

Repare também em outro detalhe: como você já fez `import math` no início, poderia usar `math.sqrt(n)` em vez de `pow(n, 1/2)` para calcular a raiz quadrada. No seu código original você acabou nem usando nada do módulo `math`, então esse `import` ficou meio "largado".

Outra opção é usar uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052):

```
import math

primos = [2, 3, 5, 7]

is_magic = [ n for n in range(8, 27) if math.sqrt(n) in primos ]
print(is_magic) # [9, 25]
```

Também removi o `cont`, que não estava sendo usado para nada. Se você quiser saber a quantidade, basta pegar o tamanho da lista `is_magic`, com `len(is_magic)`.

---

Não diretamente relacionado, mas se o `range` começa em 8, a raiz quadrada nunca será 2, então ele nem deveria estar no `if`. O mesmo vale para `7`, pois se o `range` termina em 26, a raiz quadrada nunca será maior que `5.0990195135927845`.

Mas talvez seja melhor inverter a lógica. Se eu quero verificar números mágicos dentro de um determinado intervalo, bastaria percorrer a lista de números primos, elevá-los ao quadrado e ver se eles estão no intervalo:

```
intervalo = range(8, 27)
is_magic = []
primos = [2, 3, 5, 7]
for n in primos:
    quadrado = n ** 2
    if quadrado in intervalo:
        is_magic.append(quadrado)

print(is_magic)
```

Desta forma, ficaria até mais fácil incluir vários intervalos diferentes, por exemplo:

```
primos = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37]
# números entre 8 e 26, ou entre 100 e 199
intervalo = list(range(8, 27)) + list(range(100, 200))
is_magic = []
for n in primos:
    quadrado = n ** 2
    if quadrado in intervalo:
        is_magic.append(quadrado)

print(is_magic) # [9, 25, 121, 169]
```

Se bem que assim o intervalo ficará com todos os números, pois tive que criar uma lista a partir dos *ranges* (um [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) só guarda os valores inicial e final, além do *step*). Então uma alternativa é ter uma lista de *ranges*, e aí você verifica se o valor está em algum deles:

```
primos = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37]
# números entre 8 e 26, ou entre 100 e 199
intervalos = [ range(8, 27), range(100, 200) ]
is_magic = []
for n in primos:
    quadrado = n ** 2
    # verifica se está em algum dos ranges
    if any(quadrado in r for r in intervalos):
        is_magic.append(quadrado)

print(is_magic) # [9, 25, 121, 169]
```

Claro que para isso você precisaria ter uma lista prévia dos números primos, mas de qualquer forma, no código original também precisaria (a diferença é que, se a lista for muito grande, ficaria impraticável escrever um `if valor == 2 or valor == 3 or etc...` para todos os valores possíveis).

Se não quiser escrever os números primos um a um, pode usar um [algoritmo para isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/231555/112052).

Answer (score 3):

Você está fazendo 4 condições e concatenando todas elas com o operador `or`. Até a aí tudo bem. A primeira funciona como o esperado. O problema vem nas próximas. A segunda condição é só 3, nada mais. Não é `pow(n, 0.5) == 3` como provavelmente acha que é. É só 3. E 3 é considerado um número verdadeiro. Então se essa condição é verdadeira e todas estão conectadas com `or`, tudo sempre será verdadeiro. Tem que consertar essa e as demais condições fazendo uma comparação completa. E para não ter que fazer a conta todas as vezes é melhor guardar o valor em uma variável e usar a variável para calcular.

```
import math

is_magic = []
for n in range(8, 27):
    valor = pow(n, 0.5)
    if valor == 2 or valor == 3 or valor == 5 or valor == 7:
        is_magic.append(n)
print(is_magic)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/884pBK). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/oopxzhmr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/ConditionOr.py).

Comment: Muito obrigada! E se eu quiser por mais um range? "for n in range(8, 27) and (45,33):"....tentei por assim mas não funcionou...queria poder escolher os intervalos numéricos =o

Answer (score 1):

No `if pow(n,(1/2)) == 2 or 3 or 5 or 7`
você deve comparar o resultado do pow com cada item, neste exemplo coloquei os números primos dentro de uma lista, assim usamos o operador 'in' para ver se existe dentro da lista:

```
import math

is_magic = []
primos = [2,3,5,7]

for n in range(8, 27):
    if pow(n,(1/2)) in primos:
        is_magic.append(n)

print(is_magic)
```

Você pode fazer com o conceito de list comprehension em python:

```
primos = [2,3,5,7]
is_magic = [x for x in range(8,27) if pow(x,1/2) in primos]
print(is_magic)
```

O resultado será o mesmo em ambos os casos.
Obs: seu contator `cont` não é necessário.