# Validação não entra no "if" correto

Tags: c#, if

Meu código deveria ter 4 validações e eu estou usando `if` e `else if`, porém ele só está fazendo duas delas, veja o código abaixo:

```
double salario = 0;
        double p0 = 1.20;
        double p1 = 1.15;
        double p2 = 1.10;
        double p3 = 1.05;

        Console.WriteLine("Digite o valor do salário do funcionário: ");
        salario = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (salario == 280) {
            salario = (salario * p0);
            Console.WriteLine("O salário do funcionário é: " + salario);
            Console.WriteLine("O percentual de aumento aplicado foi: " + p0);
        }
        else if (salario >= 280 || salario <= 700)
        {
            salario = (salario * p1);
            Console.WriteLine("O salário do funcionário é: " + salario);
            Console.WriteLine("O percentual de aumento aplicado foi: " + p1);
        }
        else if (salario >= 700 || salario <= 1500)
        {
            salario = (salario * p2);
            Console.WriteLine("O salário do funcionário é: " + salario);
            Console.WriteLine("O percentual de aumento aplicado foi: " + p2);
        }
        else
        {
            salario = (salario * p3);
            Console.WriteLine("O salário do funcionário é: " + salario);
            Console.WriteLine("O percentual de aumento aplicado foi: " + p3);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Pressione ENTER para sair...");
        Console.Read();
```

Quando eu coloco um valor de salário que deveria entrar no segundo `else if` que é referente a maior que 700 e menor que 1500 ele não faz com 1.10% ele faz como sendo 1.15% e eu fiz um teste para ele ir pra última condição e também não vai, ele sempre pegar 1.15%.

O enunciado da questão é essa daqui:

> 1. As Organizações Tabajara resolveram dar um aumento de salário aos seus colaboradores e lhe contrataram para desenvolver o programa que calculará os reajustes. Elabore uma rotina que receba o salário de um colaborador e o reajuste segundo o seguinte critério, baseado no salário atual: (1,0 ponto)
>
>    ```
>    a.    Salários até R$ 280,00 (incluindo):  aumento de 20%;
>    b.    Salários entre R$ 280,00 e R$ 700,00: aumento de 15%;
>    c.    Salários entre R$ 700,00 e R$ 1500,00: aumento de 10%;
>    d.    Salários de R$ 1500,00 em diante: aumento de 5%.
>    ```
>
>    Após o aumento ser realizado, informe na tela:
>
>    ```
>    a.    O salário antes do reajuste;
>    b.    O percentual de aumento aplicado;
>    c.    O valor do aumento;
>    d.    O novo salário, após o aumento.
>    ```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos, terá logo depois de aceitar).

Answer (score 3):

O maior problema é que está usando `||` quando o certo seria `&&`. Quando cai no primeiro `else if` você pergunta se é maior que 280. E é, então é verdadeiro, pronto, ele executa esse bloco e encerra. Para entender melhor: [Qual a diferença entre os operadores & e &&?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190579/101).

O código tem outros problemas, vou mostrar alguns. Um deles é [usar `double` para valor monetário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

Precisa testar se o dado foi entrado corretamente, caso contrário ele quebrará. Eu apenas retornei sem fazer nada, você pode sofisticar e dizer uma mensagem de erro ou até pedir para digitar de novo. O resto é mais cosmética que fica melhor e mais simples, concorda?

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var p0 = 1.20M;
        var p1 = 1.15M;
        var p2 = 1.10M;
        var p3 = 1.05M;
        WriteLine("Digite o valor do salário do funcionário: ");
        if (!decimal.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var salario)) return; //deu erro
        decimal perc;
        if (salario < 280) perc = p0;
        else if (salario >= 280 && salario < 700) perc = p1;
        else if (salario >= 700 && salario < 1500) perc = p2;
        else perc = p3;
        WriteLine($"O salário do funcionário é: {salario *= perc}");
        WriteLine($"O percentual de aumento aplicado foi: {perc}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/UUmc1U). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hIJxFb). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Operator/Condition.cs).