# Programa de Saque

Tags: c#

Galera eu estou tendo problema para resolver esse problema, alguém poderia me ajudar?
O problema de estudo é esse daqui:

> Em um pequeno país do planeta Cyber, a moeda vigente é o bit cuja sigla é B$. Nesta moeda existem cédulas de B$50,00, B$10,00, B$5,00 e B$1,00 bits. Você foi contratado para implementar o sistema de saques em um caixa eletrônico e, para isso, você deverá sempre liberar o menor número de notas possíveis para um determinado valor solicitado. O seu algoritmo terá como dado de entrada o valor a ser retirado do caixa e deverá emitir o total de cada nota necessário para compor o valor solicitado (de modo que este total seja o mínimo possível). (2,0 pontos).
>   O Algoritmo deverá ser encerrado quando o valor a ser retirado for 0(zero).
>   Obs: Nenhum saque poderá exceder B$1000,00 bits.
>   Exemplo:
>   Valor do Saque: 650,00
>   Notas: 6 notas de 100,00 e uma nota de 50,00

E eu fiz isso:

```
int cedCinq = 50;
int numCedCinq;
int cedDez = 10;
int numCedDez;
int cedCinc = 5;
int numCedCin;
int cedUm = 1;
int numCedUm;`

double dinheiro = 1000;
double saque, resto;

Console.WriteLine("Digite o valor que deseja sacar: ");
saque = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (saque > dinheiro)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Valor de limite excedido, não pode ser sacado esse valor!");
}
else if (saque == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Saque realizado!");
}

numCedCinq = Convert.ToInt32(saque / cedCinq);
resto = saque % cedCinq;
numCedDez = Convert.ToInt32(resto / cedDez);
resto = saque % cedDez;
numCedCin = Convert.ToInt32(resto / cedCinc);
resto = saque % numCedCin;
numCedUm = Convert.ToUInt16(resto / cedUm);
resto = saque % numCedUm;

Console.WriteLine("Do valor que foi solicitado " + saque + " foram usadas essas cédulas - Cinquenta: " + numCedCinq +
" Dez: " + numCedDez + " Cinco: " + numCedCin + " Um: " + numCedUm);
Console.ReadLine();`
```

Como posso resolver isso de um modo bem mais fácil?

Comment: Você pode usar array para isto. Conhece sobre?

Comment: Qual é sua dúvida específica? Dê uma olhada no [tour] e [ask]. Você chegou ler a resposta que dei na sua outra pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348159/101.

Comment: Sim Maniero, eu vi a sua resposta e acredito que lhe agradeci sobre ela.
A minha dúvida é se há um modo mais simples de resolver esse problema, pois não estou conseguindo deduzir de um modo diferente e também a minha resolução está com um problema que não sei resolver.

Comment: @IgorPompeo você não especificou algum problema na sua thread. Você teve dúvidas quanto a implementação, se havia um modo mais fácil.

Comment: Desculpe pessoal estou tentando resolver isso o quanto antes pois descobri que preciso desenvolver isso para hoje e fui pego de surpresa, não é merito mas enfim... O meu problema maior é a lógica de pegar o valor dividir ele e trazer o minimo de cedulas para saque daquele valor.

Comment: Se alguma resposta é útil, seja do seu post anterior ou este, marque-a como resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, fiz um código com comentários para você.
Existem outras formas de fazer, obviamente, mas acho que esta é bem simples e pode te ajudar.

Comentei o código ao inveé de explicar aqui pois enquanto escrevia já ia comentando. Se ficou alguma dúvida, comente que irei te ajudar.

```
// Aqui listamos todas os valores de cédulas que estarão disponíveis
static readonly decimal[] valorCedula  = { 50.0M, 10.0M, 5.0M, 1.0M };

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // O uso correto para valores monetários seria DECIMAL. Existem threads aqui na SOpt com informações sobre
    decimal dinheiro = 1000M;
    decimal saque = 0.0M;

    saque = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if(saque <= 0.0M || saque >= dinheiro)
        Console.WriteLine("Valor de limite excedido, não pode ser sacado esse valor!");
    else if (saque == 0.0M)
        Console.WriteLine("Saque realizado!");
    else
    {
        // Criamos uma lista de cédulas que iremos receber do tamanho máximo de cédulas disponíveis
        // Cada índice vai ser respectivo a quantas cédulas de valorCedula que será dado
        // Ou seja , cedulas[0] corresponderá a nota de 50, cedulas[1] a de 10
        int[] cedulas = new int[valorCedula.Length];

        // Fazemos um loop entre todos os valores de cédulas disponíveis
        for(int i = 0; i < valorCedula.Length; i++)
        {
            // Adicionamos no respectivo índice o valor de quantas cédulas vamos ter 
            cedulas[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(saque / valorCedula[i]));

            // Diminuímos do valo total, você pode ter uma variável auxiliar neste caso
            saque -= (cedulas[i] * valorCedula[i]);
        }

        // Escrevemos em tela
        for (int i = 0; i < cedulas.Length; i++)
            Console.WriteLine($"Cedula de { valorCedula[i] }: { cedulas[i] }");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rYnXP7)

Comment: Kevin, quando eu fui executar o seu código ele não me retornou nada, ele simplesmente aceitou o meu valor e não retornou nada e ainda fechou a tela em seguencia.

Comment: Fiz um dotnetfiddle para você ver em andamento: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rYnXP7

Comment: Eu vi Kevin obrigado.
Agora minha única dúvida sobre o seu código para conseguir entender melhor, pq vc usa isso?
`static readonly decimal[] valorCedula  = { 50.0M, 10.0M, 5.0M, 1.0M };`

Comment: Eu substitui seu `cedCinq`, `cedDez` e etc por um array de valores. Então, ai basicamente tem a mesma quantidade de variáveis que você criou mas de forma que eu possa acessá-las mais facilmente. Se houver mais cédulas que queira adicionar, basta adicionar a esta array e o trabalho já estará feito.

Comment: Blz, obrigado... agora eu entendi