# Método que retornar 03 contagens de cédulas diferentes para um saque

Tags: c#

Preciso desenvolver uma interface que realiza um saque de um caixa eletrônico.
No entanto eu preciso retornar com 3 opções de contagem de cédulas.
Por exemplo.:

Considerando cédulas de $100, $50, $20, $10, $5.

Um saque de $170,00.

Opção 01
1 cédulas = $100,00
1 cédulas = $50,00
1 cédulas = $20,00

Opção 02
3 cédulas = $50,00
1 cédulas = $20,00

Opção 03
3 cédulas = $50,00
2 cédulas = $10,00

Eu consegui achar algo parecido como na pergunta do link [Programa de Saque](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/348308/programa-de-saque), porem neste caso passa apenas a opção com menor numero de cédulas.

Como ficaria a estrutura de código para retornar 03 opções distintas de contagem de cédulas.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: E qual é a dúvida?

Comment: Peço desculpas por não ter sido claro. Eu preciso saber como seria a estrutura de código para determinar 03 tipos distintos de seleção de cédulas para um mesmo saque. Todos os exemplos que eu vi, consideram apenas o menor numero de cédulas possível.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu utilizei quase a mesma lógica que você mencionou aqui em
[Programa de Saque](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/348308/programa-de-saque)

Porém, a cada opção colocada na tela, fui retirando uma cédula disponível para fazer outras combinações com o total de 3 combinações,

```
// Cédulas existentes
static int[] Cedulas = { 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1  };
public static void Main()
{
        var saque = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        // nCedulas recebe as cedulas e é retirado uma cedula a cada opção
        int[] nCedulas = Cedulas;
        if (saque <= 0) Console.WriteLine("Valor indisponível");
        else
        {
            // esse for é o responsavel por fazer 3 opções de saque
            for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
            {
                // s recebe saque e é retirada a cada valor disponivel na cedula
                var s = saque;
                Console.WriteLine("///- OPPÇÃO" + (i + 1));

                int[] Notas = new int[nCedulas.Length];


                for (int j = 0; j < (nCedulas.Length); j++)
                {
                    Notas[j] = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(s / nCedulas[j]));
                    s -= (Notas[j] * nCedulas[j]);
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < (Notas.Length); j++)
                {
                    if(Notas[j] != 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Cedula de" + nCedulas[j] + " : " + Notas[j]);
                }
                // em nCedulas[i] pode colocar 0 para sempre remover os primeiros, com isso, na opção 2 irá remover 100 depois 50 ...20
                nCedulas = nCedulas.Where(v => v != nCedulas[i]).ToArray();
            }
          

        }
}
```

Saida do console;

```
170
///- OPPÇÃO1
Cedula de 100 : 1
Cedula de 50 : 1
Cedula de 20 : 1
///- OPPÇÃO2
Cedula de 50 : 3
Cedula de 20 : 1
///- OPPÇÃO3
Cedula de 50 : 3
Cedula de 10 : 2
```

Comment: Genial sua solução, eu não tinha enxergado este método. Agradeço pela ajuda e parabéns pela solução.