# Estou a tentar fazer um botao de pesquisa na minha view, mas diz-me que nao pode ser nulo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, linq, razor

Estou a tentar fazer um botão de pesquisa na minha *view* de filmes, mas dá-me um erro a dizer que não posso ter um valor nulo. Por que? E o que tenho de fazer?

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search)
    { 
        MovieViewModel[] movies = db.MoviesData.Select(movie => new MovieViewModel
        {
            MovieID = movie.MovieID,
            MovieName = movie.MovieName,
            MovieDescription = movie.MovieDescription,
            MovieCategory = movie.MovieCategory,
            MovieYear = movie.MovieYear
        }).ToArray();

        if (searchBy == "Categoria")
        {
            return View(movies.Where(x => x.MovieCategory==search || search == null).ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            return View(movies.Where(x => x.MovieName.StartsWith(search) || search == null).ToList());
        }
    }
```

Parte da View relativa ao botão de pesquisa:

```
<p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Movies", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <b>Search By: </b>@Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Nome", true) <text> Nome </text>
    @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Categoria") <text> Categoria </text> <br />
    @Html.TextBox("search") <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
}
</p>
```

O erro que me dá é o seguinte:

> 'System.ArgumentNullException: O valor não pode ser nulo. Nome do parâmetro: value'

Comment: Qual a linha exata em que ocorre o erro?

Comment: @RonaldoAraújoAlves dá erro nesta: return View(movies.Where(x => x.MovieName.StartsWith(search) || search == null).ToList());

Comment: Queira montar um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) com a situação real, senão fica inviável uma solução além do que já foi apresentado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro é certamente aqui:

```
return View(movies.Where(x => x.MovieName != null && (search == null || x.MovieName.StartsWith(search))).ToList());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/TestNull.cs).

Não sei se a lógica disto está correta, mas a forma adotada vai dar erro mesmo. Também não vou entrar no mérito que provavelmente está modelado errado. A questão é que se se o dado que vem é nulo você não pode chamar nada nele, por exemplo não pode chamar `StartsWith()` porque não tem um objeto válido ali para executar algo. Então tem que prevenir que este dado não seja comparado. Não posso dizer que fiz certo porque a pergunta não deixa claro o que deveria fazer. Inverti a comparação também porque se passar um `null` para o método `StartsWith()` também dará erro.

Comment: esta dando o mesmo erro que no comentário abaixo. The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebApplication3.Models.MovieViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WebApplication3.Models.MovieViewModel[]'      MovieViewModel é onde tenho as propriedades todas dos filmes

Comment: Aí é outro problema em outro lugar. O que perguntou foi resolvido. Cada pergunta deve conter um problema. Mas antes de resolver isso você precisa entender o que quer, e postar na pergunta, as pessoas não podem adivinhar o que precisa, não é só postar o código. Uma pergunta completa tem todas informações necessárias. Sem saber o que precisa qualquer resposta estará errada, porque mesmo que funcione, não estará certa, funcionar por coincidência não é certo.

Comment: Então a pergunta já não disse em que linha era o erro, agora não diz o que quer fazer. Você precisa entender o que é programação antes de programar. Você está gerando uma lista de dados, é isto que quer? Na *view*  está lidando com um dado, é isto que quer? Eles são mutualmente exclusivos, ou pega um dado ou lista todos dados, mas novamente esta é outra questão.

Comment: Peço desculpa, sou bem novo no stack overflow, na minha cabeça o que estava postando estava correto, vou ter mais atenção em relação às minhas perguntas. Vou então explicar então o meu objetivo. Na minha view tem uma lista de filmes que vem da base de dados. E em cima tem um botão, 2 radio buttons(para escolher se quer pesquisar nome ou categoria) e uma caixa de texto para a pesquisa. O que eu quero que essa parte do programa faça é que pesquise filmes, por nome ou categoria. O erro que apareceu, antes de por o código para pesquisa não aparecia. Mais uma vez, peço desculpa.

Answer (score 1):

O problema ocorre porque o `search` está `null`.

Inverta a ordem.
De

```
x => x.MovieCategory==search || search == null
```

Mude para

```
x => search == null || x.MovieCategory==search
```

O motivo é que o `StartsWith` lança uma exception se o valor passado for `null`.

Quando se faz `||`, o .net primeiro verifica a condição anterior ao `||` e depois a posterior. Se a primeira já atender (no caso do OR, for `true`), ele não passa pela segunda.

[Mais detalhes sobre os operadores || e |](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/190590/144579)

Comment: Mas assim dá um erro no 'x', no '=>' e outra vez no 'x'

Comment: Utilizou assim?
`return View(movies.Where(x => search == null || x.MovieName.StartsWith(search)).ToList());`

Comment: eita, deu um erro muito maior agora: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebApplication3.Models.MovieViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WebApplication3.Models.MovieViewModel[]'.

Comment: Bom, aí é outro erro. Provavelmente sua view espera um `MovieViewModel[]` mas você está passando uma lista (afinal, está utilizando o `.ToList()`. Mas eu sugeriria criar uma pergunta para cada erro diferente, isso facilita os futuros usuários que tiverem o mesmo problema a encontrarem a solução com mais facilidade.