# Qual a diferença entre estas duas expressões booleanas?

Tags: tabela-verdade, álgebra-booleana

Estou verificando a tabela verdade [neste site](http://brinks.guisehn.com/tabela-vdd/) sobre as seguintes expressões:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém cada uma delas me resulta em uma saída diferente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi qual é a dúvida.

Comment: @Maniero olá meu amigo novamente. Para mim estas duas expressões booleanas são idênticas as duas possuem essas duas entradas barradas, correto? Porém no site que utilizei para gerar a tabela verdade, as mesmas me geram uma saída diferente da outra, isto me mostra que as duas expressões não são idênticas. A minha pergunta foi em cima disto, pois agora estou em dúvida e queria saber qual a diferença das duas se não forem realmente iguais.

Comment: Se a tabela verdade das duas são diferentes então obviamente existe diferença entre as duas expressões.

Comment: @anonimo isso é obvio, não? Porém a questão que eu quero saber, é o porque da diferença...

Comment: Então estude os teoremas de De Morgan da álgebra booleana que verá que ¬(A AND B) = ¬A OR ¬B e também que ¬(A OR B ) = ¬A AND ¬B.

Comment: É uma relação de identidade, amigo. Isso é baseado nas leis de De Morgan, e é verdade pelo mesmo motivo que 1 + 1 = 2. Se você é um rapaz das práticas basta executar um LogiSim e montar o circuito citado acima. Você vai observar que este é um comportamento de identidade, já reduzido em sua forma mais básica. Em outras palavras, é tipo uma daquelas fórmulas de matemática que você "precisa" decorar. O seu resultado é diferente porque `negar duas portas com AND` e `negar a saída de duas portas com AND` é essencialmente diferente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É uma questão de precedência de operações, como ocorre na matemática (multiplicação e divisão sempre ocorrem antes que adição e subtração a não ser que tenha algo os agrupando, como o uso de parênteses), ou em toda expressão em códigos que escrevemos no computador, acho que posso posso falar assim porque já conhece isso.

A imagem é clara para quem conhece bem o assunto, mas as tabelas que estão na pergunta deixam mais claro até para quem não conhece isso que é bem diferente.

O ponto é um operador lógico AND ([já falei sobre ele em código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190579/101)) que diz que para o resultado ser verdadeiro os dois operando devem ser verdadeiros, o resto sempre dá falso. O apóstrofo nega o operando dele (NOT), ou seja, o que é verdadeira vira falso e vice versa. Os parenteses agrupam a operação e o que está dentro deve ser realizado antes do que está fora, portanto o que está fora operará com o resultado de tudo o que está ali dentro.

Então na primeira tabela pega B e o nega, afinal o operador de negação está próximo dele. Ele tem prioridade sobre o outro operador. C também é negado. Com os dois valores negados procede-se a relação de E. A primeira expressão tem 0 e 0, então ambos são negados individualmente, e ficam 1, aí 1 E 1 dá 1. Na segunda linha e demais é feito o mesmo, mas como sempre pelo menos um deles fica 0, o E exige que ambos sejam 1 para dar 1, então o resultado é 0.

A segunda tabela muda por causa dos parenteses. B é relacionado com C através da operação de E e esse resultado obtido é negado pelo operador que está valendo para todo o valor resultando dentro dos parenteses. Nas três primeiras linhas há um 0, então o resultado será 0 porque o E exigue que ambos sejam 1 para dar 1, aí dando 0 há uma negação e o resultado final fica 1. Na última linha ambos são 1, então dá 1 e negado o final dá 0.

As tabelas estão invertidas em relação à imagem.

Comment: Obrigado meu amigo!

Answer (score 0):

Após ler alguns livros, estou respondendo a minha própria pergunta com mais detalhes e dando ênfase ao que realmente é importante e a qual foi o intuito da pergunta..

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seguindo a **Tabela Verdade** acima é possível notar a diferença entre as **portas lógicas** e o mais importante, que é o **"tipo de simbologia da barragem" das entradas"**.

Utilizando estas entradas como exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Podemos observar que as saídas de [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] é diferente de [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui], pela seguinte questão:

- A **primeira expressão booleana** está barrando as entradas `A` e `B`
- A **segunda expressão booleana** está barrando as saídas da porta lógica `AND` das entradas `A` e `B`. Sabendo-se disto com a **"simbológica desta barragem"**, devemos aplicar o **Teorema de De Morgan**.

**Nota**

> Com a aplicação do teorema na segunda expressão podemos observar que na verdade ela é: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] **(tanto que esta mesma expressão booleana possui a mesma saída da expressão booleana** [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]**).**
>
> O mesmo vale para a expressão booleana [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui], quando aplicado o teorema citado esta expressão é equivalente a: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].

Comment: Sendo bem sincero, achei que a outra resposta respondeu de forma mais completa a pergunta. A sua resposta basicamente copiou o que já tinha na pergunta e citou vagamente o teorema de De Morgan. Pelo texto, basicamente é dito que é diferente porque é diferente. Talvez completar a resposta com o uso a fundo do teorema e **mostrar** porque as tabelas verdades são diferentes ficaria mais completa.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss a resposta do usuário acima foi aceita, porém complementei a minha com um pouco mais de ênfase no que realmente eu queria saber, não expliquei utilizando o tereoma de demorgan pois eu já estou supondo que os outros usuários saibam o mesmo, apliquei apenas o raciocínio correto que deve ser para os dois tipos de expressões lógicas, obrigado.