# Concatenar variáveis em C

Tags: c

É possível concatenar 2 variáveis de tipos diferentes e obter uma só variável que ocupe os mesmo bytes que a soma dos bytes das 2 variáveis de tipos diferentes?

Por exemplo:

```
short int A=9999;
unsigned char B=110;
```

E obter uma variável C que ocupe 3 bytes e contenha 9999110.

Comment: Pode usar struct + union, só precisa tomar cuidado com a _endianness_ do sistema usado para deixar na ordem certa. Só que juntando os bytes não dá isso que você disse, seria outro valor. 9999110 não é concatenação de 9999 + 110, não confunda dígitos com bytes

Comment: Não, os tipos de dado básicos da linguagem C tem tamanho predeterminado. Além disso a operação de concatenação é definida para strings e não para outros tipos de dado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe como fazer o que perguntou, mas o resultado provavelmente não é o que espera.

- Para declarar uma estrutura em C, você tem a `struct` (que é literalmente estrutura);
- Para fazer com que dois membros apontem para o mesmo espaço da memória, você tem o `union` (união).

Dá para usar as duas coisas, e para isso fiz um exemplo. No caso, para que o `int` e o `char` "coubessem" em outra variável, precisei de um "pad" (enchimento), para dar os quatro bytes do `double` usado no exemplo.

### Pondo em prática:

Veja o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

union {
    struct  {
        short int A;
        unsigned char B;
        unsigned char pad; // só para ficar com 4 bytes, igual o long a seguir
    };
    long result; // Por estarem dentro de uma Union, tanto a struct acima
                 // quanto o long estarão no mesmo espaço.
                 // São nomes diferentes para o mesmo dado
                 // (ou partes dele no caso de A e B.

} x;

int main(void) {
    x.A = 0x8899;  // Usei hexadecimal para ficar evidente o funcionamento
    x.B = 0xCC;    // E propositalmente pus em maiúscula para diferir do resultado
    x.pad = 0;
    printf("%x",x.result);
}
```

Resultado:

> ```
> cc8899
> ```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/sDwkhU)**.

Dependendo da "endianness" do ambiente, poderia ter ficado invertida a ordem dos bytes. Aí você tem que entender melhor o conceito se for trabalhar com ambientes híbridos.

### Conclusão

A parte boa é que você sabe que dá para concatenar *bytes* na memória em C e pegar numa "variável" só (no caso um membro da struct).

A ruim é que os bytes se comportam como bytes, e em nada se assemelham à concatenação de digitos decimais (que é coisa de humano, pra máquina o que interessa é potência de 2).

Em hexadecimal você vê claramente que os bytes se juntaram, mas se tentar usar decimais, pode estranhar o resultado ao exibir em notação "humana" (decimal).

Leitura complementar:

> [Como funcionam os números em hexadecimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13573/70)
>
> [O que é big-endian e qual a diferença para little-endian?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50457/70)